# Nested functions and parent variables?

Tags: python

When I run the code below:

```
def run():
  test = False
  def tester():
    if not test:
      print("test is false")
    else:
      print("test is true")
    test = not test
  tester()
run()
```

I get the error:

> local variable 'test' referenced before assignment

I was under the impression that the child function would have access to the parent functions variables.  After playing with this code a bit I've found that if I remove the assignment (`test = not test`) then everything works fine.

Why does having an assignment in the child function break this code?  If I shouldn't have the assignment in the child function, what would be the best way to toggle the `test` flag?  Should I just return a value from the child function and use that to toggle `test`?

Comment: Because the compiler/interpreter detects an assignment within the `tester` function, `test` becomes a local variable. Which then, naturally, has no value assigned to in the `if` statement.

Comment: Have you tried `nonlocal test`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419379/how-to-maintain-lists-and-dictionaries-between-function-calls-in-python should help you.

Answer (score 3):

Python 2 doesn't support assignments to variables closed over by a nested function.  The usual workaround is to put the value in a mutable container (*e.g.*, a one-element list).  Python 3 offers the `nonlocal` keyword for this purpose.

Comment: Would using `nonlocal` be similar to using a global variable? I've heard that using global variables for things like this is generally bad practice - would using `nonlocal` be bad practice as well?

Comment: `nonlocal`'s socpe is function but not global, so as far as I think it is not a bad practice as `global` is.