# Does a list defined in a functions parameter body acts as a static variable in python?

Tags: python, list, function, local-variables

Here, the list is defined as a local variable in the parameter of the function `foo`, but I'm confused why even on repeated calls the list still remembers it's previous values, why is it acting like a static variable?

```
def foo(character,my_list = []):
    my_list.append(character)
    print(my_list)

foo("a")
foo('b')
foo('c')
```

---- Output ----

```
['a']
['a','b']
['a','b','c']
```

Comment: because default arguments are evaluated *once* at function definition time. In a sense, you can think of them as static variables like C if that helps you remember it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Okay! thanks,  but btw if I ever wanted to achieve the functionality of a static variable then would it be alright to use this approach?

Comment: it wouldn't exactly be equivalent, because you can pass *any* object to that argument.

Comment: Check out [this question that I answered a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56811860/c-like-static-variable-inside-a-python-class-method/) on what you can do to have something like a C static variable (it's not going to be a perfect fit...)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga okay thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define a mutable value as default argument, what python does is something like this:

```py
default_list = []
def foo(character, my_list=default_list):
    my_list.append(character)
```

The same happens for any other mutable type (`dict` for instance). 
You can find a very detailed explanation here: https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html

One way you can make an empty list as a default for a list can be:

```
def foo(character, my_list=None):
    if my_list is None:
        my_list = []
    my_list.append(character)
```

Comment: Well, it works this way *for all objects*, just it only really becomes an issue with mutable objects

Comment: It's true, and here is a very long discussion about this on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the [common gotchas](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/):

> Python’s default arguments are evaluated once when the function is
>   defined, not each time the function is called (like it is in say,
>   Ruby). This means that if you use a mutable default argument and
>   mutate it, you will and have mutated that object for all future calls
>   to the function as well.