# Why is this a type error and not a syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, typeerror

Why would the code

```
print("Average =" (sum/count))
```

produce a type error and not a syntax error, seeing as a comma is missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python treats the `()` as a function call; strings are not callable resulting in a `TypeError`:

```
>>> "somestring"(42)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

In Python, *everything* is an object; functions are objects too, any object could implement a `__call__` method, making every object potentially callable. Python won't know that the string object is not callable until runtime, so this is not a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Just to put it into context though, `print(sum (sum/count))` also results in a type error, even though all variables involved are integers, so how does this relate to strings not being callable?

Comment: @user2975192: Integers are not callable either. `sum` is an integer.

Comment: @user2975192: If you were expecting `sum` to be the built-in function, then you cannot use it like that because you masked it by assigning a different value to `sum` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The interpreter is seeing the line as a function call, function which has to be `"Average ="`, but it's impossible because `str` aren't callable. So you get a type error exception.

```
>>> print("Average =" (sum/count))
 #        ^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^
 #         fct name        arg1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

A callable object is a object where its class implemented the `__call__` function. It's useful in some case (see the link below), but the `str` type doesn't implement it (because it has no sense).
More info about callable object: [Python __call__ special method practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824881/python-call-special-method-practical-example)

Answer (score 0):

That's valid syntax for a function call (what if `"Average ="` was replaced with a method name?), and you can't call a string.