# Python self takes args, self(args)

Tags: python, self

I'm not quite understand what this code mean:

```
# instantiate the input layer
x = Input(batch_shape=batch_input_shape,
          dtype=input_dtype, name=name)
# this will build the current layer
# and create the node connecting the current layer
# to the input layer we just created.
self(x)
```

This code is inside a member function of a class, please refer to https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/topology.py line 341.
When I step into the self(x), it jumps to another member function __call__ of this class. Why does this happen? Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__

Comment: An object can be callable if its class has a `__call__` method.  `self` is the current object.  When you call an object then control is passed to `__call__` - as you found.  You can test if this is supported by using the built-in function `callable()`.

Comment: @cdarke Thanks for your explanation. I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

[`__call__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) is one of the special methods in Python. It allows classes to emulate function types.

`self` is probably --as by convention-- the first argument to your member function, i.e. the instance of the object the method is called on.

`self()` thus uses the current instance object as a function. By definition, this means that the `__call__()` method on the object will be invoked, which is exactly what happens.

Comment: this seems legit, could you give an example of why a callable object would be useful?

Comment: @CaffeineAddiction have a look at [Python `__call__` special method practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5824881/1942027)

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl Thanks