# How to use 'expected conditions' to check for an element in python-selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I have trouble understanding how to use an 'expected conditions' to check for the presence of an element. Given [this documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) it is not clear at all how to use this. I have tried the following code

```
 def _kernel_is_idle(self):
    return EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="kernel_indicator_icon" and @title="Kernel Idle"]'))
```

with the idea of checking an element (callable as a method within a class). There are two things that do not make any sense:

1. According to the documentation (I had to look up the source code!), this method should return either `True` or `False`. However, it returns the following:

   ```
   <selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located object at 0x110321b90>
   ```
2. How can this function work without a `webdriver`? Usually you always have a call like

   ```
   driver.do_something()
   ```

but where is the referece to the webdriver for an 'expected condition'?

Comment: Can you explain why do you need such kind of method instead of just using common built-in Selenium methods and properties?

Comment: Yes maybe. Do the common built-in selenium methods return `False` in case an element is not there? Like `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button')`? Or do I have to do `try/except`?

Comment: `visibility_of_element_located` intend to check whether element is visible. Tha same you can try to do with `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button').is_displayed()`. If you want to check presence of element you can try `bool(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button'))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems you were almost there.

The [**`Documentation`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) clearly says the following:

```
class selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(locator)
```

Which is defined as :

> **An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0. locator - used to find the element `returns the WebElement once it is located and visible`**

Hence, when you mention:

```
return EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="kernel_indicator_icon" and @title="Kernel Idle"]'))
```

The found out `WebElement` is being returned as follows :

```
<selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located object at 0x110321b90>
```

Even the [**`Source Code`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.html#visibility_of_element_located) says the same as :

```
try:
    return _element_if_visible(_find_element(driver, self.locator))
```

When the search is unsuccessfull :

```
except StaleElementReferenceException:
    return False
```

Comment: `<selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located object at 0x110321b90>` is not a WebElement, but just an instance of `visibility_of_element_located()` class. To get WebElement it should be called as `EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="kernel_indicator_icon" and @title="Kernel Idle"]'))(driver)`

Comment: Unless we cast the `driver` instance and invoke the `EC`, we shouldn't expect the `WebElement` anyway, right? We would see the instance only.

Comment: Yes, in the way OP use it (`return EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="kernel_indicator_icon" and @title="Kernel Idle"]'))`) we will not get WebElement

Comment: That's right. But the way OP invoked EC what ever he is seeing is pretty correct.

Answer (score 10):

To summarize in a more organized manner:

- Expected Condition is a *callable* (could be a function or a class with [`__call__()` magic method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5824881/771848) defined)
- Expected Condition is supposed to be used inside the `until()` method of a [`WebDriverWait()` instance](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait):

  ```
  wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
  wait.until(<Expected_condition_here>)
  ```
- the result of an Expected Condition does not have to be just `True`/`False`. The result would be tested on truthiness by the `WebDriverWait`. Note: a `WebElement` instance is "truthy". Read more about truthiness in Python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/771848)
- it is quite convenient that when an Expected Condition returns a `WebElement` instance. It allows to have a link to an element right away without the need to find it again:

  ```
  button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "my_id")))
  button.click()
  ```
- you can write your own [custom Expected Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19377437/771848)

Answer (score 2):

The way `expected conditions` work is by defining a `WebDriverWait`. You create this with an instance of your `WebDriver` and a timeout. The `WebDriverWait` has an `until()` method which will take an `expected condition` and will wait until it has been met or until the timeout has passed. So instead of just `EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="kernel_indicator_icon" and @title="Kernel Idle"]'))` you should use:

```
WebDriverWait(yourdriver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="kernel_indicator_icon" and @title="Kernel Idle"]')))
```

**Edit**
I should note that this doesn't return `True` or `False`. This will return the `WebElement` if it has been found and is visible. Otherwise it will raise a `TimeOutException`. [Source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py#L115)

Comment: No. It will not return `False` in case element not found during timeout, but `TimeOutException`

Comment: @Andersson You're right. I'll edit my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're almost success! What you want could be:

```
def _kernel_is_idle(self):
    return EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="kernel_indicator_icon" and @title="Kernel Idle"]')
    )(driver)
```

Here, you should pass the webdriver object as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to import expected_conditions module from selenium.webdriver.support.
With this module you can check several conditions of the element with giving expected time as well

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://domain/element")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "idxxx"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Answers with just code are frowned upon. You should add a description to your answer :)

Comment: @MBorg I have added the description