# Can I make json.dumps/loads work with Encoder/Decoder instances instead of classes?

Tags: python, json

Please consider this toy example of a custom JSON-encoder.

```
import json
from typing import Any

class MyNumber:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

class MultEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    'Multiply MyNumber instances when JSON-encoding.'

    def default(self, o: Any) -> Any:
        if isinstance(o, MyNumber):
            return o.num*2
        return super().default(o)
```

It works like this:

```
>>> json.dumps({"a": MyNumber(5)}, cls=MultEncoder)
'{"a": 10}'
```

My question is how can I make the factor dynamic? I would like to do:

```
class MultEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    'Multiply MyNumber instances when JSON-encoding.'
    
    def __init__(self, factor, *args, **kwargs):
        self.factor = factor        
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def default(self, o: Any) -> Any:
        if isinstance(o, MyNumber):
            return o.num*self.factor
        return super().default(o)
```

But of course, `json.dumps({"a": MyNumber(5)}, cls=MultEncoder(7))` fails with

```
TypeError: 'MultEncoder' object is not callable
```

because the `cls` argument is expected to be a class, not an instance.

edit1: Note that I cannot write custom `my_json_dumps`/`my_json_loads` functions, I can only control which encoder/decoder classes get imported in other parts of the code where `json.dumps` and `loads` are used.

edit2: Note that I tried to make a general, simple example. In my real code the encoder/decoder need to know credentials for connecting to a database and other dynamic configuration.

Comment: If you pass the factor through `MyNumber` object, does that work for you?

Comment: @MohammadRifatArefin I'm sorry, can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: If you add a new member `factor` in the `MyNumber` class and then use this factor in the `default` method in the `MultEncoder` class, then you can call `json.dumps` in this fashion `json.dumps({"a": MyNumber(5,7)}, cls=MultEncoder)`

Comment: @MohammadRifatArefin ah thank you, that's clever. Unfortunately this will only work for this specific example, not in my real code where I cannot expect other programmers to set "magic attributes" on all instances of the objects that will be json-encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `MultEncoder` class instances callable by simply adding the `__call__` method.

```
class MyNumber:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
class MultEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    'Multiply MyNumber instances when JSON-encoding.'
    
    def __init__(self, factor, *args, **kwargs):
        self.factor = factor        
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def __call__(self,**kwargs):
        return self

    def default(self, o: Any) -> Any:
        if isinstance(o, MyNumber):
            return o.num*self.factor
        return super().default(o)
json.dumps({"a": MyNumber(5)}, cls=MultEncoder(7))
```

And the output is:

```
'{"a": 35}'
```

Comment: That's so elegant! Thank you.

Comment: @actual_panda Thanks! it might be an interesting read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48461989/python-what-does-it-mean-for-a-class-to-be-callable

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a pretty ugly solution: a class-factory function where the returned class accesses closure-variables.

```
def MultEncoder(factor):
    class _MultEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
        'Multiply MyNumber instances when JSON-encoding.'

        def default(self, o: Any) -> Any:
            if isinstance(o, MyNumber):
                return o.num*factor
            return super().default(o)

    return _MultEncoder
```

Demo:

```
>>> json.dumps({"a": MyNumber(5)}, cls=MultEncoder(7))
'{"a": 35}'
```

Is this the best we can do here?