# python keras syntax Conv2D

Tags: python, syntax, keras

I'm pretty new to python and deep learning. From one of the kaggle kernels I saw the following code and i'm trying to understand the logic behind this syntax:

```
c1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (s)
c1 = Dropout(0.1) (c1)
c1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c1)
p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c1)

c2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p1)
c2 = Dropout(0.1) (c2)
c2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c2)
p2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c2)
```

I don't understand the `(s), (c1), (c2)` at the end of the statements...could anyone please explain the logic behind this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax of Keras Functional API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022273/syntax-of-keras-functional-api)

Answer (score 0):

(s), (c1), (c2) is the input of corrrsponding layer