# How would I create a "type" of a Callable?

Tags: c#, python-3.x, typescript, types

Is there a Pythonic way of creating a [Callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#callable) type like below (TypeScript and C# examples)?

**TypeScript:**

```
export type MyHandler = (paramOne: ClassOne, num: int) => null;
```

**C#:**

```
public delegate void MyHandler(ClassOne paramOne, int num);
```

---

**Python:**

```
MyHandler = Callable[[ClassOne, int], None]  # No lint errors...
```

While I'm not getting any lint errors in PyCharm; I haven't bothered running my snippet yet because of how *not*-Pythonic this feels. If this was going to be my own code for private consumption I don't think I would bother with creating this type, but it's going to be part of a library so I feel more obligated to create the type.

In usage, this type would show up in something like:

```
class SomeClass(ProbablyAnABC):
    # __init__ where self._handlers is created

    def register_handler(self, handler: MyHandler) -> None:
        self._handlers.append(handler)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Callable[[ClassOne, int], None]`?  I wouldn't get too worked up about it. The best thing you can do for readability is coming up with a more descriptive name than `MyHandler`

Comment: In python you need to think about types yourself or try to execute your code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489669/function-parameter-types-in-python. Here is link about '_call_' it may be helpfull in your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824881/python-call-special-method-practical-example.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, thanks for catching that missing opening bracket; the current names are placeholder names for the question.

Comment: @Vayrex, thank you for those links they have been very helpful.