# tensorflow 2.0, when calling the function two variables given, but, when defining the function, there is no variables

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tf.keras, tensorflow2.0

I was following the tutorial in [tensorflow-2.0](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/generative/dcgan). When defining the generator, there were no variables given, but when calling the function, there are two variables are given.

```
def generator_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(7*7*256, use_bias=False, input_shape=(100,)))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Reshape((7, 7, 256)))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 7, 7, 256) # Note: None is the batch size

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 7, 7, 128)
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 14, 14, 64)
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False, activation='tanh'))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 28, 28, 1)

    return model


generator = generator_model()
noise = tf.random.normal([1, 100])
generated_image = generator(noise, training=False)
```

This is an official tutorial in tensorflow site.

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: There is no error, I just wonder why I can give two variables to the generator.

Comment: Would be better to include the whole `generator_model` function code (edited & included it myself).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`def generator_model()` creates and returns model object. And then you can give data into the generator object to generate an image. There is no contradiction. `def generator_model()` only creates the generator object which will be used later.

As you can see here [https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/Sequential#**call**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/Sequential#__call__)

`tf.keras.Sequential()` object has `__call__` function which means you can call the instance.([Python __call__ special method practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824881/python-call-special-method-practical-example)) And it just wraps another call function as stated.

Comment: @Kit. not quite sure what you mean or imply here