# Python: cache a local function variable for subsequent calls

Tags: python, global-variables, local-variables

In C/C++, a function can declare a local variable as `static`. When doing so, the value remains in memory and is available to subsequent calls to the function (this variable is no longer local, but that's besides the point).

Is there a way to do something similar in Python, **without** having to declare any global variable outside of the function?

Use case: a function that (among other things) uses a regex to extract a value from an input string. I want to pre-compile the pattern (`re.compile()`), without having to declare the variable outside of the function scope.

I can inject a variable directly into `globals()`:

```py
globals()['my_pattern'] = re.compile(...)
```

But it doesn't look like a good idea.

Comment: Why not just use a **class**?

Comment: i dont think so

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat in the given context, everything is static (single functions) and a class won't really help.

Comment: @JakubDóka me neither, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: You can tackle this with a decorator the caching  would happen there. You profile looks experienced enough so I can be lazy and not give you an  example 

Comment: You can use a persistent default argument to preserve state between calls. See ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: @noamtm classes are the solution see [S.Lott's answer on - Simulating a 'local static' variable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/460811/14991864) just make the class callable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a function attribute. In Python, functions are first-class objects, so you can abuse of this feature to simulate a static variable:

```py
import re

def find_some_pattern(b):
    if getattr(find_some_pattern, 'a', None) is None:
        find_some_pattern.a = re.compile(r'^[A-Z]+\_(\d{1,2})$')
    m = find_some_pattern.a.match(b)
    if m is not None:
        return m.groups()[0]
    return 'NO MATCH'
```

Now, you ca try it:

```py
try:
    print(find_some_pattern.a)
except AttributeError:
    print('No attribute a yet!')

for s in ('AAAA_1', 'aaa_1', 'BBBB_3', 'BB_333'):
    print(find_some_pattern(s))

print(find_some_pattern.a)
```

This is the output:

```sh
No attribute a yet!
initialize a!
1
NO MATCH
3
NO MATCH
re.compile('^[A-Z]+\\_(\\d{1,2})$')
```

It is not the best approach (wrappers or callables are way more elegant, and I suggest you use one of them), but I thought this clearly explains the meaning of:

> In Python, functions are first-class objects.

Comment: I like it better than the other ideas suggested in the comments.