# matplotlib get rid of max_open_warning output

Tags: matplotlib, runtime, warnings

I wrote a script that calls functions from QIIME to build a bunch of plots among other things.  Everything runs fine to completion, but matplotlib always throws the following feedback for every plot it creates (super annoying):

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py:412: RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_num_figures`).
> max_open_warning, RuntimeWarning)

I found [this page](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html?highlight=max_open_warning) which seems to explain how to fix this problem , but after I follow directions, nothing changes:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['figure.max_open_warning'] = 0
```

I went into the file after calling matplotlib directly from python to see which rcparams file I should be investigating and manually changed the 20 to 0.  Still no change.  In case the documentation was incorrect, I also changed it to 1000, and still am getting the same warning messages.

I understand that this could be a problem for people running on computers with limited power, but that isn't a problem in my case.  How can I make this feedback go away permanently?

Comment: Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884271/warning-about-too-many-open-figures

Comment: There is just one opening quote missing before the dictionary key, otherwise this is correct!

Answer (score 47):

Try setting it this way:

```
import matplotlib as plt
plt.rcParams.update({'figure.max_open_warning': 0})
```

Not sure exactly why this works, but it mirrors the way I have changed the font size in the past and seems to fix the warnings for me.

Answer (score 13):

Another way I just tried and it worked:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rc('figure', max_open_warning = 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this article](https://heitorpb.github.io/bla/2020/03/18/close-matplotlib-figures) which basically says to `plt.close(fig1)` after you're done with fig1. This way you don't have too many figs floating around in memory.

Answer (score 2):

In Matplotlib, figure.max_open_warning is a configuration parameter that determines the maximum number of figures that can be opened before a warning is issued. By default, the value of this parameter is 20. This means that if you open more than 20 figures in a single Matplotlib session, you will see a warning message. You can change the value of this parameter by using the matplotlib.rcParams function. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.max_open_warning'] = 50
```

This will set the value of `figure.max_open_warning` to 50, so that you will see a warning message if you open more than 50 figures in a single Matplotlib session.

Answer (score 0):

When using *Seaborn* you can do it like this

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(rc={'figure.max_open_warning': 0})
```