# Unable to plot graph in google colab

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I am trying to plot the graph in google colab

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.title("Weight matrices after model trained")
plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
plt.title("Trained model Weights")
ax = sns.violinplot(y=h1_w,color='b')
plt.xlabel('Hidden Layer 1')

plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
plt.title("Trained model Weights")
ax = sns.violinplot(y=h2_w, color='r')
plt.xlabel('Hidden Layer 2 ')

plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
plt.title("Trained model Weights")
ax = sns.violinplot(y=out_w,color='y')
plt.xlabel('Output Layer ')
plt.show()
```

The graph is not getting plotted and also its showing a warning - /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:8: RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_open_warning`).

How ro resolve this issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib get rid of max\_open\_warning output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476642/matplotlib-get-rid-of-max-open-warning-output)

Comment: Now, the warning is removed. but still the graph is not getting plotted. Nothing is showing after plt.show() command

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you've inadvertently enabled a different matplotlib plotting backend (perhaps you changed the backend using the `%matplotlib` magic?)

To get your plotting back to normal, either restart your runtime, or in the current runtime run

```
%matplotlib inline
plt.close('all')
```

and in the future, avoid changing the plotting backend.