# Closing figure show vs. imshow

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, inline, figure

Normally, I use following figure-closing pattern to prevent [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884271/warning-about-too-many-open-figures)

```
%matplotlib inline

plt.figure()
// plot here what necessary
plt.show()
// figure is displayed inline
plt.close()
```

Replacing [show](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html) with [imshow](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html), within **for in** loop only 1 last figure is displayed.

How to plot inline in loop with imshow, making sure that closing figures properly?

Comment: `show` shows a figure. `imshow` plots an image to a figure. They are completely unrelated and you cannot replace one by the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244309/closing-figure-show-vs-imshow?noredirect=1#comment89467111_51244309)

```
for x in y:
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(...)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```