# plt.close('all') doesn't get rid of 'too many figures' warning

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a script that runs repeatedly and in the process it saves a figure into a folder. After a while I start getting warnings about too many open figures in memory.

I checked other questions on the topic, for example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884271/warning-about-too-many-open-figures) and added `plt.close('all')` to my code so now it looks like this:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(17,8))
plt.hist(results_df['Diff'], bins=100, density=True, histtype='step')
plt.savefig(f'backtester_results/figures/rf_model_{n_days}_data_and_{lag}_lag.png',
                format='png')
plt.close('all')
```

And yet I keep getting figures piled up in memory and warnings after a while. Where did I go wrong?

Here's the warning:

```
RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (matplotlib.pyplot.figure) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory.
```

Comment: Please include the warnings that you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading in the official documentation I would assume that `plt.close('all')` only closes the windows without removing the figures (https://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.close).

As I understand you would need to clear the figure as follows:

```
fig.clf()
plt.close()
```

Source: ([How can I release memory after creating matplotlib figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101404/how-can-i-release-memory-after-creating-matplotlib-figures))