# Closing figures from previous sessions

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, memory

I am running a python code that produces some figures with Matplotlib and Pandas. After a few runs of the code, I am getting to following error:

> RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created
> through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained
> until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control
> this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_open_warning`)

I think this is because I forgot to close the figures after each run of the code. I have tried

```
plt.close('all')
```

but it does not close the figures from previous sessions. Restarting the terminal (conda) did not help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a really similar issue with really good and detailed answers in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884271/warning-about-too-many-open-figures).

I can tell you that you are probably creating figures in a loop or over and over with more than one execution, so you need to use the methods `.clf` and `.cla` to close the figures you are creating. But, you have all the detailed info in the above thread.

Comment: The solutions in the thread you suggested work on the current run, however, will not close/delete figures open in previous sessions.

Comment: Try this solution: run `fig.gcf()` this should close the figure and childs, but it may tell you that this command does not exist. Also found that this other solution worked for other people: 
   plt.show(block=False);
   time.sleep(5);
   plt.close('all'). 
Source: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8560/

Comment: fig.gcf() did not work, becuase I've been creating figures with pandas: `df.plot.hist()`. without creating fig objects as such (that was apparently a big mistake). The other fix did not work either, unfortunately.

Comment: @Kasia If you didn't create a fig object, pandas will automatically create one for you. You can access it via `fig = plt.gcf()` ("get current figure"). If you only want to close the current figure, you can use `plt.clf()`.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out that the figures I had open were not figures from previous sessions but figures created in multiple loops on the current session. Adding `plt.close('all')` after each loop solved the problem. @JohanC thanks for the hint about pandas automatically creating fig objects, it is good to know in the future how to access these objects.