# Does Matplotlib add variables to our namespace and how does it store data?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I usually see Matplotlib being used like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

years = [1980, 1990, 2000, 2010]
gdp = [300, 400, 520, 700]
plt.plot(years, gdp, marker='o')
plt.show()
```

does that actually create or use a bunch of variables scoped to plt?  (such as `plt.someKindOfPlotDataArray`)

I sometimes see Matplotlib used as:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show

years = [1980, 1990, 2000, 2010]
gdp = [300, 400, 520, 700] 
plot(years, gdp, marker='o')
show()
```

which is to directly import `plot` and `show` into our namespace.  If used this way, doesn't it potentially add variables or instance variables to our code?  (or else, how can `plot` add data and then `show` will be able to use it?  Does the import add these 2 methods `plot` and `show` to the current object?  But when Python runs, is it as if it is running inside a method of a global object?  If so, if we just import `plot` and `show`, what if `plot` actually needs another method from the module, such as `plotHelper`?)

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is essentially: "How does matplotlib's state machine interface work?".  I'll answer that in a second.

However, let's back up and answer the import question first.

### Namespaces and `import from`

Say we have a file name `foo.py` with the following contents:

```
DUMMY = 1

def talk():
    print DUMMY
```

And then we do:

```
from foo import talk
talk()
```

The function will still work as expected, even though `DUMMY` is nowhere in the namespace that we're working in.

If we do:

```
print DUMMY
```

We'll get a `NameError`.

Instead on injecting things into the current namespace, each function keeps track of the namespace in which it was created.  In this case:

```
assert 'DUMMY' in talk.__globals__
```

With that out of the way, let's get back to `matplotlib`

---

### The `matplotlib` State Machine

Matplotlib's `pyplot` interface uses a state machine to keep track of the currently active figure, axes, image, etc.  It's meant to directly mirror Matlab's approach for an easier transition from Matlab to Python.

However, you'll typically use an object-oriented approach when using `matplotlib`, and limit the usage of `pyplot` to a couple of convenience functions: `plt.subplots()` or `plt.figure()` and `plt.show()`.

Let's break down a simple example using only the `pyplot` interface and explain the steps that matplotlib takes.

For example, if we do something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(10))
plt.show()
```

What happens? `plt.plot` is basically a one-liner. It's `return plt.gca().plot(*args, **kwargs)`.  Essentially, it boils down to this:

1. `plt.plot` tries to get the current `Axes` instance.
2. Because there hasn't been one created yet, it creates a `Figure` and adds an `Axes` to it.
3. The `Axes` instance's `plot` method is called and a line is added to the axes (the line object is also returned).
4. The gui mainloop for the `Figure` is entered when we call `show`

If all this seems a bit indirect, it is.  That's why shouldn't be using that style.  Instead, use the standard object-oriented interface.  That way it's much clearer what Axes you're plotting on, which Figure you're saving, etc.

With that in mind, let's back up and use the more common style instead of the matlab-esque `plt.plot`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(10))
plt.show()
```

Here, we've used a few `pyplot` functions to create a new figure/axes and display the figure.  You can skip them entirely, but it gets a touch verbose.

Basically:

1. `subplots` creates a new `Figure` instance (`fig`) and adds one or more `Axes` (subplots) to the figure.  By default, a single Axes (`ax`) will be added to the figure.
2. We add a line to the `Axes` instance by calling its `plot` method (`ax.plot(data)`).
3. We enter the gui mainloop with `plt.show()`.

Hopefully that clarifies things a touch.  If you're still struggling, you might have a look through the documentation or a few other SO questions. For example:

- http://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html
- [Prevent matplotlib statefulness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28631741/prevent-matplotlib-statefulness)
- [python matplotlib blit to axes or sides of the figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14844223/python-matplotlib-blit-to-axes-or-sides-of-the-figure/14846126#14846126/28633419#28633419) (Second half of answer)

Comment: so `talk()` is like a closure that captures the scope at the place it was defined?

Comment: @太極者無極而生 - Yep! Though technically, a closure only happens when you're dealing with nested functions.  In that case, the variables in the "outer" function's scope would be stored in `talk.__closure__`.   At any rate, you can think of all functions in Python as being closures in the sense that they preserve the scope that they're defined in.  (There are caveats there that I'll skip for brevity, though.)