# tkinter, matplotlib: memory usage

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory, matplotlib, tkinter

I've got a simple program that creates a GUI using `tkinter`. The GUI contains a button that creates a new tkinter `Toplevel` window each time it is pressed. Each toplevel window contains a matplotlib plot created from a custom `Figure` class.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from Tkinter import *

class MainGUI(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        Button(self, text="new_child", command=self.new_child).pack()
        self.mainloop()

    def new_child(self):
        self.tl = TL()

class TL(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, **kw)
        self.data = "00000000000"*10000000  # just some data to analyze memory allocation 
        self._figure = MyFigure(self.data)
        self._canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self._figure, master=self)
        self._canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NSWE")

class MyFigure(Figure):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(MyFigure, self).__init__()
        self._data = data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainGUI()
```

The program works as expected, the only problem is that closing a window doesn't free up any memory.

When removing the `Figure` from the toplevel window, used memory gets freed correctly, so I assume that the `Figure` causes the memory leak.

I read that reference counting doesn't work for `Figure` objects that are created using matplotlibs pyplot interface, but this should not apply to my example. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334588/create-a-figure-that-is-reference-counted/16337909#16337909) for details)

I don't understand what's going on here, so any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

#### Edit

I forgot to mention that I already tried to manually invoke the garbage collector with `gc.collect()`, but that didn't help.

Comment: How do you do your test? I would expect the garbage collector to clean up the memory eventually, assuming the object is no longer in use.

Comment: I already tried to manually invoke the gc, but that didn't help. The test is pretty straight-forward. Open/Close child windows, you'll see that the memory used by the program increases with each created child window.

Comment: could you not override the `destroy` method of you `TL` class to remove the figure before destroying the window?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `gc.collect()` **after** the toplevel window has been closed:

```
def new_child(self):
    tl = TL()
    self.wait_window(tl)   # Wait for tl to be closed before continuing execution
    del tl
    gc.collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this question, and for the answer which helped me a lot. I have found myself in a similar situation with a slightly more complex GUI. I experienced memory leaks despite applying the solution given here. It seems that adding **traces to Tkinter variables** (e.g. IntVar, DoubleVar, etc) prevents the Toplevel window from being properly destroyed, and causes leaks. **Manually removing the traces** on destroy fixes this issue. Let me give an example of a code which suffers a leak, and the fix I found. I hope it helps others.

Preliminary:
First of all, use the corrected version of `new_child` given by Josselin:

```
def new_child(self):
    tl = TL()
    self.wait_window(tl)   # Wait for tl to be closed before continuing execution
    del tl
    gc.collect()
```

Then, the code **with a memory leak** (caused by the trace):

```
class TL(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, **kw)
        self.number = IntVar()
        self.data = "00000000000"*10000000  # just some data to analyze memory allocation 
        self._figure = MyFigure(self.data)
        self._canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self._figure, master=self)
        self._canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NSWE")
        Spinbox(self, from_=0, to=10, textvariable=self.number).grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.number.trace('w', self.updateSomething)
    def updateSomething(self, *args): return
```

And finally, **the fix** (remove manually the traces on destroy):

```
class TL(Toplevel):
    def destroy(self):
        for var, s, trid in self.allTraces: var.trace_vdelete(s, trid) #manually removes traces. Otherwise: memory leak!
        super(TL, self).destroy()
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, **kw)
        self.allTraces = []
        self.number = IntVar()
        self.data = "00000000000"*10000000  # just some data to analyze memory allocation 
        self._figure = MyFigure(self.data)
        self._canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self._figure, master=self)
        self._canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NSWE")
        Spinbox(self, from_=0, to=10, textvariable=self.number).grid(row=1,column=0)
        trid = self.number.trace('w', self.updateSomething)
        self.allTraces.append((self.number, 'w', trid))
    def updateSomething(self, *args): return
```