# close() not releasing memory after matplotlib savefig

Tags: python, matplotlib, memory

I'm running a python program which replots a graph every few minutes, but every time it runs the memory it uses goes up a little bit, and soon the raspberry pi I'm using slows to a crawl.

Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
from memory_profiler import profile

@profile
def plotter(file_name, plot_name):
    with open(filen_name, 'r') as readings:
        reader = csv.reader(readings, delimiter=',')
        data = [row for row in reader]

    plt.plot(data[2], data[0])
    ax = gca()
    xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%H:%M') # xaxis is datetimes
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
    plt.legend()

    plt.savefig(plot_name, transparent=True)
    plt.clf()
    plt.cla()
    plt.close()
```

And the function is called with something like:

```
 while True:
     plotter(file_name, plot_name)
     sleep(100)
```

The memory_profiler spits out nice output, but it always looks like this:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
38     36.2 MiB      0.6 MiB       plt.savefig(plot_name, transparent=True)
39     36.2 MiB      0.0 MiB       plt.clf()
40     36.2 MiB      0.0 MiB       plt.cla()
41     36.2 MiB      0.0 MiB       plt.close()
```

(The rest of the function doesn't increase memory usage.)
The memory is incrementing up at `savefig()`, but is never released despite the various ways I've tried to close the figure.
Anyone know why the `close()` doesn't release the memory?

---

Edit:
I've tried another method.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot( some arguments)
fig.savefig(filename)

plt.close('all')
del ax, fig
```

This doesn't decrement the memory usage either.

---

Edit 2:
From this answer elsewhere ([Create a figure that is reference counted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334588/create-a-figure-that-is-reference-counted/16337909#16337909)) I've tried the following:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_svg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

fig = Figure()
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot etc...
fig.savefig(file_name)
plt.close('all')
```

This also doesn't seem to work. Memory still increasing monotonically and always at the `savefig` line of the function.

Comment: maybe force the call to garbage collector? also try `plt = None`

Comment: "it always looks like this" So mem usage is always 36.2 MiB? That does not look like a problem.

Comment: @Goyo Sorry, what I meant was the pattern always looks like this. I.e., all lines increment=0 except the `savefig` line which increments by some value.

Comment: @user3087409 I tried to replicate the issue and gave up after fixing the fourth error I got running your code. Maybe make it a [mcve] instead of just relevant.

Comment: @user3087409 The backend might be important too.

Comment: @Goyo I'm using the SVG backend

Comment: I wonder why the first edit method does not work. The second edit method will not work since `pyplot` is not aware of the figure you created outside of pyplot using FigureCanvas. In this case, `del fig, canvas` could help. In general, are you sure, that the garbage collector is not collecting the deleted elements?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre if (semantically speaking) you want to get rid of the name `plt`, use `del plt`. If you actually want it to point to `None`, use `plt = None`. But you probably meant the former. Both should reduce the reference count of whatever `plt` was referring to, but `del` is what signals the actual intent here.

Answer (score 8):

I encountered the same issue. After looking around I found a solution: you need to close the fig AND all windows.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
plt.plot(X, Y)
fig.savefig(img_name)
fig.clf()
plt.close()
```

After closing both the plot and figure, my memory stayed at a more or less constant level.

You can also close the axis using:

```
ax.cla()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        # Clear the current axes.
        plt.cla() 
        # Clear the current figure.
        plt.clf() 
        # Closes all the figure windows.
        plt.close('all')   
        plt.close(fig)
        gc.collect()
```

Try adding these lines at the end of the loop! It worked for me. (for sub-plot)