# How to clear matplotlib graphs from memory

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I was running code earlier and got the following warning:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "<string>", line 558
RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through 
the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly 
closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam
`figure.max_open_warning`).

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "<string>", line 665
RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through 
the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly 
closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam 
`figure.max_open_warning`).
```

Not going to lie, I was being very careless and was still running it anyway, ignoring the warning.
Now whenever I try to run the script, my python shell doesn't run the script.

So I am trying to remove the graphs from the memory to allow me to run script again.

I have tried the following and it still won't let me run the code:

1. `plt.clf()`
2. `plt.cla()`
3. `f = plt.figure()` `f.clear()` `plt.close(f)`
4. `plt.close('all')`
5. `matplotlib.pyplot.figure().clear()`
   `matplotlib.pyplot.close()`

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8519

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46933292/close-not-releasing-memory-after-matplotlib-savefig

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib._pylab_helpers as pylhelp

pylhelp.Gcf().destroy_all()
```

Though this would work for what you want, this is not a supported interface and might become obsolete. I do not know of any other way of doing this, that is the only reason I recommend it.

Comment: oh wait sorry this works. I made a mistake somewhere