# matplotlib memory leak on MacOS

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, memory-leaks

I have faced a matplotlib memory leakage problem while working on my python project that I can't solve. Nothing I found regarding this problem helped. Here is a very simplified script causing aforementioned behaviour:

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
​
fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(500):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    plt.savefig(f'test{i:03d}.png')
    fig.clear()
```

This is the memory usage plot I'm getting on various operating systems:

- MacOS 12.2.1, matplotlib 3.5.1: [image]
- Win 11, matplotlib 3.5.1: [image]

The issue seems to be MacOS related.

Steps to reproduce the plots:

- `pip install memory-profiler`. I used `memory-profiler` tool, but any other profiling tool can be used as well.
- `mprof run test.py`
- `mprof plot`

Solutions I've tried that didn't help:

- https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/20300
- [How can I release memory after creating matplotlib figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101404/how-can-i-release-memory-after-creating-matplotlib-figures?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [close() not releasing memory after matplotlib savefig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46933292/close-not-releasing-memory-after-matplotlib-savefig)