# Matplotlib doesn't release memory after savefig and close()

Tags: python, matplotlib, memory-leaks

I have a piece of code that works fine looping once or twice but eventually it builds up memory. I tried to locate the memory leakage with `memory_profiler` and this is the result:

```
row_nr    Memory_usage    Memory_diff    row_text
 470     52.699 MiB     0.000 MiB      ax.axis('off')
 471     167.504 MiB    114.805 MiB    fig.savefig('figname.png', dpi=600)
 472     167.504 MiB    0.000 MiB      fig.clf()
 473     109.711 MiB    -57.793 MiB    plt.close()
 474     109.711 MiB    0.000 MiB      gc.collect()`
```

I created the figure like this:
`fig, ax = plt.subplots()`

Any suggestion where the 109 - 52 = 57 MiB went?

I am using python 3.3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125710/matplotlib-errors-result-in-a-memory-leak-how-can-i-free-up-that-memory Although that's a workaround, not  a clear solution to this problem.

Comment: this question is more generic, probably one of the scenarios there covers your case. If not, let us know more details of use case in question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101404/how-can-i-release-memory-after-creating-matplotlib-figures.

Comment: Thanks for the try, unfortunately it work, I'm not running anything in django so that didn't help. I can try the multiprocessing but as stated that just avoid the problem and doesn't solve it. I'm using subplots ("fig, ax= plt.subplots()" ) so I can't change from fig = plt.figure() to fig = figure.Figure(), or? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try `plt.close('all')` at the end of each loop. Works for me with the `agg` backend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken from here: [Matplotlib errors result in a memory leak. How can I free up that memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125710/matplotlib-errors-result-in-a-memory-leak-how-can-i-free-up-that-memory)

Which has original ref: https://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg11809.html

To get ax and figure do:

instead of:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
```

use:

```
from matplotlib import figure
fig = figure.Figure()
ax = fig.subplots(1)
```

Also no need to do `plt.close()` or anything. It worked for me.

Answer (score 18):

Nothing posted here worked for me. In my case, it had something to do with running on a server via SSH interpreter. Apparently this will use a non-interactive mode, and that started clearing all memory as normal:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

Source: https://matplotlib.org/stable/faq/howto_faq.html#work-with-threads

Comment: This answer should be accepted. It is a known bug in matplotlib https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/20300

Comment: This reduced the ram usage from GBs to MBs. Thank you! As you said, none of the other posts worked for me.

Comment: In my case, it was not related to SSH, I was running a Python script (saving figures) in my local.

Comment: Also running from Python from Eclipse, from 30GB by end of run to a consistent 100MB. Tried everything else to no avail.

Comment: Thanks so much! Not sure if this is a bug or not, but it has been driving me crazy. Setting the backend resolves the issue. No other methods worked. Also it is a local python script in my case, not SSH related

Answer (score 10):

```
# Clear the current axes.
plt.cla() 
# Clear the current figure.
plt.clf() 
# Closes all the figure windows.
plt.close('all')
```

Hope this can help you

Comment: also add ```import gc; gc.collect()``` to make sure you clear the memory!

Answer (score 4):

`plt.ioff()` worked for me in notebook,
`plt.close(fig)` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

```py
# Clear the current axes.
plt.cla() 
# Clear the current figure.
plt.clf() 
# Closes all the figure windows.
plt.close('all')   
plt.close(fig)
gc.collect()
```

This worked for me. Just put these lines at the end of the loop!