# Why librosa.load() Runs Out of Memory when generating spectrograms?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, kaggle, librosa

I am working on classifying sounds with Deep Learning and my problem is that I run out of memory when I try to convert .wav files to spectrograms using lib.load() from librosa.

```
split = ['train','val']
categories=['URTI', 'Healthy', 'Asthma', 'COPD', 'LRTI', 'Bronchiectasis','Pneumonia', 'Bronchiolitis']
files_loc = "path"
i=0

for s in split:
    for cat in categories:
        print('-' * 100)
        print('working on ' + cat +" "+str(s)+" "+ '...')
        print('-' * 100)

        files = [f for f in listdir(files_loc + s + '/' + cat + '/') if isfile(join(files_loc + s + '/' + cat + '/', f)) and is_wav(f)]

        for f in files:
            convert_to_spec_image(file_loc = files_loc, category=cat, filename=f, is_train=(s == 'train'), verbose=False)
            i=i+1
            print("We have processed: "+str(i)+" "+ str((i/773*100))+" % "+" so far")
```

The function convert_to_spec_image is this:

```
#create images using librosa spectogram
def convert_to_spec_image(file_loc, filename, category, is_train=False, verbose=False):
    ''' 
        Converts audio file to spec image
        Input file includes path
        Saves the file to a png image in the save_directory
    '''
    train_ = 'train/'
    val_ = 'val/'
    
    loc = file_loc + train_ + category + '/' + filename
    if is_train == False:
        loc = file_loc + val_ + category + '/' + filename

    if verbose == True:
        print('reading and converting ' + filename + '...')
        
    y, sr = lb.load(loc)

    #Plot signal in
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,3))
    src_ft = lb.stft(y)
    src_db = lb.amplitude_to_db(abs(src_ft))
    specshow(src_db, sr=sr, x_axis='time', y_axis='hz')  
    plt.ylim(0, 5000)
    

    save_directory = "C:/Users/raulf/Desktop/espectograms2/"
    filename_img = filename.split('.wav')[0]
    
    save_loc = save_directory + train_ + category + '/' + filename_img + '.png'
    if is_train == False:
        save_loc = save_directory + val_ + category + '/' + filename_img + '.png'
        
    plt.savefig(save_loc)
    plt.close('all')

    if verbose == True:
        print(filename + ' converted!')
        
    plt.close('all')
```

I am trying to reuse the code from this Kaggle Notebook:
https://www.kaggle.com/danaelisanicolas/cnn-part-3-create-spectrogram-images

Thanks in advance

Comment: How big are your audio files?

Comment: Around 1.5 to 2.5 MB and I want to processs 6898 files. I manage to convert all my audio files, but I needed to do it in batches and in every batch I restarted the Jupyter Notebook. 

Doing it in batches is a little bit tedious so I want to know why is that my memory is going up a lot and it increases while I process more files. I think it has something to do in letting something opened, but is the first time I work with audio data.

Thanks Hendrik

Comment: I have never had that issue... Does this also occur, when you run the code from the command line?

Comment: No, I have not. I will try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

I happened to have the same issue and share my findings.
`librosa.load` may have memory leak issue, but not in your case, check [this link](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/1286).
Your issue comes from `specshow` with `matplotlib` related.
I suggest to use non-interactive mode for `matplotlib`:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

And close all the resources, something like:

```
y, sr = librosa.load(audio_path)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
spec = np.abs(librosa.stft(y, hop_length=512))
spec = librosa.amplitude_to_db(spec, ref=np.max)
color_mesh = librosa.display.specshow(spec, sr=sr, x_axis='time', y_axis='log', ax=ax)
ax.set(title='Spectrogram')
fig.colorbar(color_mesh, format='%+2.0f dB', ax=ax)
fig.savefig('Spectrogram.jpg')

fig.clear()
plt.cla()
plt.clf()
plt.close('all')
del color_mesh
del ax
del fig
```

referred [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156578/matplotlib-doesnt-release-memory-after-savefig-and-close)