# Looping through a list using multiprocessing.pool()

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm calling a function with large memory overhead on a list of `N` files.  The reasons for the large memory overhead are due to a number of factors that cannot be resolved without modifying the function, however I have overcome the leaking memory using the `multiprocessing` module. By creating a subprocess for each of the `N` files, and then calling `pool.close()`, the memory from the function is released with minimal overhead.  I have achieved this in the following example:

```
def my_function(n):
    do_something(file=n)
    return 


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Initialize pool
    for n in range(0,N,1):
        pool = mp.Pool(processes=1)
        results = pool.map(my_function,[n])
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

This does exactly what I want: by setting `processes=1` in `pool`, one file is run at a time for  `N` files. After each `n` file, I call `pool.close()`, which closes the process and releases the memory back to the OS.  Before, I didn't use `multiprocessing` at all, just a `for` loop, and the memory would accumulate until my system crashed.

My questions are

1. Is this the correct way to implement this?
2. Is there a better way to implement this?
3. Is there a way to run more than one process at a time (`processes>1`), and still have the memory released after each `n`?

I'm just learning about the `multiprocessing` module.  I've found many `multiprocessing` examples here, but none specific to this problem.  I'll appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the correct way to implement this?

"Correct" is a value judgement in this case.
One could consider this either a bodge or a clever hack.

> Is there a better way to implement this?

Yes. Fix `my_function` so that it doesn't leak memory.
If a Python function is leaking lots of memory, chances are you are doing something wrong.

> Is there a way to run more than one process at a time (processes>1), and still have the memory released after each n?

Yes. Use the `maxtasksperchild` argument when creating a `Pool`.

Comment: This worked! I also had to set `chunksize=1` for `pool.map()`.  Fixing the function is not feasible; the memory leak is due to a longstanding issue with how matplotlib retains references that cannot be removed or collected by garbage collection, and as a result, a large number of plots causes the memory leak.  I have found a similar post to said leak and this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125710/matplotlib-errors-result-in-a-memory-leak-how-can-i-free-up-that-memory/7125856  Thank you!