# Garbage collection for matplotlib figures

Tags: python, matplotlib, memory, garbage-collection, figure

Various sources ([e.g. this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12300012/13326516)) make it sound like garbage collection occurs properly for figures created with `matplotlib.figure.Figure()` but not for figures created with `matplotlib.pyplot.figure()`. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find documentation of this.

Is it true that Python will garbage collect old figures created with `matplotlib.figure.Figure()` that are no longer used? For example...

- If I assign `fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure()` inside a function, will the memory for this figure be cleared up when the function ends (assuming I don't do something like `return fig`)?
- If I assign `fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure()`, will the memory for the figure immediately be cleared up if I then assign `fig = 23`?

Thank you!

(I apologize if this isn't actually "garbage collection." If so, let me know. )

Edit: fixed typo

Answer (score 2):

The `matplotlib.pyplot.figure` documentation states you should explicitly call `pyplot.close` on the figures you are not using. Otherwise pyplot will not properly clean up memory. Check out the notes at the bottom [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But this does not actually address the question. (This may be because the question initially had a typo, now fixed—sorry about that.)