# Python3 - Matplotlib FuncAnimation continuous memoryleak

Tags: python, tkinter, memory-management, raspberry-pi

**EDIT2:**

So after some more work I created the smallest sample which reproduces the Memoryleak pretty decent on every machine.
This code just creates a TKinter Window and a matplotlib canvas with 3 Sine waves, than tries to animate then. See that blit is true, so it shoudnt do anything because the drawing does not change.

I also tried following ways from this post
[How can I release memory after creating matplotlib figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101404/how-can-i-release-memory-after-creating-matplotlib-figures)

**gc.collect()** - did nothing

**axes.clear** - it did stop endless memory to be leaked but also completely screws the picture

**figure.clf** - same as clear but worse.

Any other idea why FuncAnimation increases in memory usage over time?????
Thanks

```
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread
from numpy import sin, cos, pi


#--Mainwindow--
class Drehstromdemonstrator(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        #Predefine

        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Minimal")
        
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  

        self.frame = plotSine(self,(tk.Tk.winfo_screenwidth(self)*0.7,tk.Tk.winfo_screenheight(self)*0.7))


      
import numpy,matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from numpy import sin, cos, pi, deg2rad, linspace, arange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.ticker as tck
import time
import math


from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from math import ceil

global U1ausg, U2ausg, U3ausg, Counter_1, Counter_2, Counter_3

U1ausg = U2ausg = U3ausg = Counter_3 = 50
Counter_1 = 120
Counter_2 = 240


class plotSine:

    def __init__(self,masterframe,size):
        self._running = True

        global U1ausg
        global U2ausg
        global U3ausg

        (w,h) = size
        inchsize = (w/25.5, h/25.4)
        fig = self.figure = Figure(inchsize)

        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.axes.xaxis.set_ticks(arange(0,390,30))
        self.axes.margins(x=0)
        self.axes.yaxis.set_ticks(arange(-120,130,20))
        self.axes.set_ylim(-120,120)

        #create canvas as matplotlib drawing area
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=masterframe)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        self.x = linspace(0,360,1000)
        self.axes.grid()


        #self.drawStuff()

    #Draw the plot
    def drawStuff(self,*args):       
        ax = self.axes
       

        self.axes.legend(["U1","U2","U3"])

        #Changed everything to degree instead of PI, better looking
        ysin = int(ceil(U1ausg))*sin(50/Counter_3 * deg2rad(self.x))
        ysin2 = int(ceil(U2ausg))*sin(50/Counter_3 * deg2rad(self.x) + deg2rad(Counter_1))
        ysin3 = int(ceil(U3ausg))*sin(50/Counter_3 * deg2rad(self.x) + deg2rad(Counter_2))

        lineU1 = ax.plot(self.x, ysin, "-r",label="U1")
        lineU2 = ax.plot(self.x, ysin2, "-g",label="U2")
        lineU3 = ax.plot(self.x, ysin3, "-b",label="U3")

        

        return [*lineU1,*lineU2,*lineU3]

    #Animation to redraw when value changed
    def animate(self):
        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.figure, self.drawStuff, interval=10, blit=True)


#--Run Mainprog

try:
    app = Drehstromdemonstrator()
    plt.show()
    app.frame.animate()
    app.mainloop
# Aufraeumarbeiten nachdem das Programm beendet wurde
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    print("Interrupt aswell!")
    lampensteuerung.terminate()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Interrupt")
    lampensteuerung.terminate()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

---

**EDIT1:**

By try-and-error I could figure out that the problem seems to be in my matplotlib, as if I disable it the memory increase stops.

---

So my task is to finish this project from someone else - it simulates a 3-phased system via a raspberry and some lights. When I disable the GUI the code works splendid, no problems, fast reaction. Sometimes the PI says he has low voltage but I just think that is some weird bug because the sourcepower is really enough to power it.

Full Code removed because not needed.

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem!

Comment: gpio callbacks are called in context of non-main thread. You need to pass message from that callback thread into main thread to control GUI.

Comment: I try to overlook the code and reduce it!
Could you elaborate the callback problem ? - The GPIOs work fine with and without GUI also the controll of the GUI works fine aswell its just the memory problem. Thanks