# pointer changes value without being passed as argument

Tags: c, pointers

Following is a code snippet from a code involving some transformations on a binary tree.

```
void fixPrevPtr(struct node *root)
{
    static struct node *pre = NULL;

    if (root != NULL)
    {
        fixPrevPtr(root->left);
        root->left = pre;
        pre = root;
        fixPrevPtr(root->right);
    }
}
```

Here **'pre'** is initialised in every function as NULL. But when function entered **'if'** clause and     **root->left=pre**, was executed, pre that was being assigned was not NULL. It was somehow changed by the function **fixPrevPtr(root->left)**.

My question is that how does it get changed without being even passed into the function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you understand what `static` does?

Comment: @KerrekSB Honestly, does he seem so?

Comment: @KerrekSB... honestly, I am embarassed...I just didn't see the static before node...I work in c++, so I overlook struct keyword used while defining variables as done in c. When, I was going through the code, maybe due to sheer callousness, I overlooked static along with struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pre` is static so it keeps it's value from call to call.  `fixPrevPtr()` is recursive (calls itself) so any change to `pre` "sticks".

Answer (score 3):

This bit is incorrect

> Here 'pre' is initialized in every function as NULL.

It only gets initialized once due to the static keyword. If the function changes the value then next time the function has that value instead of null.

Answer (score 2):

```
static struct node *pre = NULL;
```

Initialize `pre` once due to the `static` keyword.

But the next time you enter in this function, `pre` will have the last value assigned to it.

I suggest you to read this : [Static variable inside of a function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033627/static-variable-inside-of-a-function-in-c)

In the C standard :

> **6.2.4 Storage durations of objects**
>
> An object whose identifier is declared with external or internal linkage, or with the storage-class specifier **static** has *static storage duration*. Its lifetime is the entire execution of the program and **its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup**.

Answer (score 0):

`pre` is a static value , it stored in the `data segment`, and it scope is not only the `fixPrevPtr` but also the all other function in this  process, so of course `fixPrevPtr` itself can change it.

Answer (score 0):

you have added `static` keyword with the `struct node * pre = NULL` that's why it is retaining a value from a previous function call when `pre = root;` was executed.
remove `static` and you are good to go

you can read about static variables from this link http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap14/subsection2.1.1.6.html

> Static automatic variables continue to exist even after the block in which they are defined terminates. Thus, the value of a static variable in a function is retained between repeated function calls to the same function.