# Does Julia support static variables with function-scope

Tags: static, julia

In C, one can declare static variables with local function scope ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033627/static-variable-inside-of-a-function-in-c)).

Can something similar be done in Julia?

My use case is declaring sub-functions, but do not want Julia to have to reparse them every time the code executes. Declaring them outside of the function is ugly and gives them higher scope, which I want to avoid.

example:

```
function foo(x)
    static bar = t -> stuff with t

    ...
    bar(y)
    ...
end
```

While I could declare bar() outside of foo(), I would prefer bar to only be in the local namespace.

Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a new scope around the function, to hold the variable.

```
let
    global foo
    function bar(t)
        #stuff with t
    end
    y = 2
    function foo(x)
        #...
        bar(y)
        #...
    end
end
```

Then only `foo(x)` will be visible to the outside

Answer (score 5):

Based on @ivarne's answer.

```
let bar = t -> t^2
    global foo
    function foo(x)
        bar(x)
    end
end
```

But I don't think this is an ideal solution. IMHO it would be better to have a `static` keyword. The extra block is unwieldy. There is some discussion about this in Julia development:

https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/15056

https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/12627

Answer (score 4):

Note that `y` needs to be a let variable in @ivarne's answer, or it will overwrite any `y` in global scope:

```
julia> y = 4
4

julia> let
           global foo
           function bar(t)
               #stuff with t
           end
           y = 2
           function foo(x)
               #...
               bar(y)
               #...
           end
       end
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> y
2
```