# storing values in functions while calling multiple times

Tags: c

I doubt regarding c program, how to store values in a function,if I call a function the variables are initialized and previous values are deleted so how can I store values in functions.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include "buzzer.h"

void ReachDestinationAvoidingNode(unsigned char Xd,unsigned char Yd,unsigned char Xn,unsigned char Yn)
{

}


//Do not make changes in main function

int main(void)
{
       ReachDestinationAvoidingNode(5,'D',6,'D');
       buzzer_on();
       _delay_ms(500);
       buzzer_off();
       ReachDestinationAvoidingNode(2,'F',2,'D');
       buzzer_on();
       _delay_ms(500);
       buzzer_off();
       ReachDestinationAvoidingNode(2,'A',2,'C');
       buzzer_on();

}
```

now when the `ReachDestinationAvoidingNode(5,'D',6,'D')` function is called the `5,D` values should be stored and again when the  `ReachDestinationAvoidingNode(2,'F',2,'D')` called the `5,D` values should be used. how to do that,
without disturbing main code

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033627/static-variable-inside-of-a-function-in-c

Comment: Why don't you use call by reference?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can add four extra  class variables in your code as memXd,memYd,memXn,memYn and initialize them with null value.
And in your ReachDestinationAvoidingNode() method just initialize them with new value at the end of your function. Like

```
    unsigned char memXd='';
    unsigned char memYd='';
    unsigned char memXn='';
    unsigned char memYn='';
    void ReachDestinationAvoidingNode(unsigned char Xd,unsigned char Yd,unsigned char Xn,unsigned char Yn)
     {
        //do your stuff;
        memXd=Xd;
        memYd=Yd;
        memXd=Xn;
        memYd=Yn;
        // by this your function will always remember previous value you can use it in your code
     }
     int main(void)
     {
       ReachDestinationAvoidingNode(5,'D',6,'D');
       buzzer_on();
       _delay_ms(500);
       buzzer_off();
       ReachDestinationAvoidingNode(2,'F',2,'D');
       buzzer_on();
       _delay_ms(500);
       buzzer_off();
       ReachDestinationAvoidingNode(2,'A',2,'C');
       buzzer_on();

     }
```

Comment: i have done what you have said but it is showing error as empty char constant what to do

Comment: you have to add a check in function whether it is emplty or not ,if empty- it means you are visiting that function for first time.

Comment: This is seriously confusing. "Class variables" don't exist in C, and variables cannot be "empty".