# Difference between static and local variable inside a function scope

Tags: c, recursion

I am trying to find the number of digits in the input integer.
But it always prints "no. of digits: 1".
In place of getting integer `i` from function, if I use "`static int i = 0;`" inside the function it works perfectly.
And I can't understand this behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int a, int i)    
{  
    if (a != 0) 
    {
        i++;
        func(a / 10, i);
    }

    return i;   
}

int main()
{
    int a, c;
    printf("Enter the No:");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    c = func(a, 0);
    printf("No. of digits: %d", c);
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: You are not using the return value of the recursive `func` call. You need to. By changing it to `static` the variable has lifetime beyond the lifetime of the function. That is, it is the same variable for all invocations of the function. (And it hides the `i` passed into the function).

Comment: What is `func` supposed to do? It's hard to understand what "works perfectly" or "doesn't work" mean, when we have no idea what it's supposed to do

Comment: I think the OP intended for `func(a, 0)` to return the number of decimal digits in A, roughly speaking.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursion repeatedly refreshes the memory for your function at every call.
ts the same, it is like the same question between `global variable` and `local variable`. When you do not use `static`, every call to your function will refresh your variable `i` and initialize it again. When you use `static`, the variable `i` will be the same as a global variable with just once statement.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question about static:

It is unclear where you want to use `static int i = 0;`  as alternative.
Inside the function, (and removing the function arg i) it becomes a variable that is kept in memory even after the function exits. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033627/static-variable-inside-of-a-function-in-c) for reference. If it is outside of a function look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-c) for reference.

Regarding your code:
Your code is not using the result of your recursive function call. It is neither stored inside the local variable i, nor returned directly. It is simply lost. See a code example below, that might be want you want.

**EDIT:** The variable i in the original answer was unnecessary, so I'll remove it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int a) {
    if (a == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + func(a / 10);
}

int main() {
    int a, c;
    printf("Enter the No:");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    c = func(a, 0);
    printf("%d", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now this should be stored somewhere
but still problem exist

int func(int a, int i) 

{

    if (a == 0)

    {

        return 0;

    }

    i++;

    func(a / 10, i);

    return i;

}

Comment: I'm not entirely understanding what problem you have. If I run that code on my laptop and enter e.g. the value 9992 via the console, I get 4.
What problem are you referring to?

Comment: Since the `i` argument in this answer is set but never read, it can be removed.

Comment: Ah right I see. Yeah, the I will edit the response.