# python: how to access attributes of functions

Tags: python, lookup, member-functions

I'm trying to access attributes of member functions, but I cannot understand why I can access only through the `__dict__`.

```
class A(object):
    def fA(self):
        print A.fA.x 
    fA.x = 2

A.fA.__dict__['x'] = 3 
#A.fa.x #AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'x'
A.fA.x = 4
```

Why I do get an AttributeError if I try to access 'directly'?

Comment: You are trying to add attributes on the method in the class definition?

Comment: Why exactly do you want this?

Comment: I want this because it's a python feature. 
At the beginning I did something similar when I want derived classes to set the attribute of one of their methods. 
I need the right pointers to the answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to add attributes. But what I care more is to understand how the language works. I know it can easily became bad practice.

Comment: Reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891277/why-does-setattr-fail-on-a-bound-method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of how `instancemethod` objects are implemented. They use a non-standard attribute-getter which doesn't allow access to non-standard attributes.

Comment: That's the kind of answer I wanted. Can you tell me where I can read more? I also would like to know what non-standard attributes are. Nobody told me of this notion!!

Comment: Read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891277/why-does-setattr-fail-on-a-bound-method

Comment: That link suggests its not a certain amount of attributes. But rather the inability to do it on bound or unbound methods.

Comment: `instancemethod` is a class that's implemented in C as part of the CPython implementation. As such, it doesn't have the built-in flexibility that normal Python objects have. It does have a `__dict__` (because the C implementation provides it), but its `__getattribute__` doesn't automatically map to things in that dict.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you'd ever do this, but...

A.fA is actually a completely separate object vs the function fA. Watch:

```
>>> class A(object):
...   def fA(self): pass
...   print fA
... 
<function fA at 0x10f1c2a28>
>>> A.fA
<unbound method A.fA>
```

As you can see, A.fA is an "unbound method", not a function. "Unbound" means that it's not associated with any instance; whereas, bound methods are tied to a specific instance. Observe:

```
>>> A().fA
<bound method A.fA of <__main__.A object at 0x10f1d3d10>>
```

Either way, methods wrap the functions that implement them:

```
>>> A.fA.im_func
<function fA at 0x10f1c2a28>
```

Notice that the address is the same as the one printed earlier.

Strangely, I cannot repro the behavior you see:

```
>>> A.fA.__dict__['x'] = 1
>>> A.fA.x
1
```

Perhaps, this difference is due to different versions of python. Here's mine:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

PS: A.fA.x seems to work for me just as well as A.fA.im_func.x, which surprises me... Again, I'm a little suspicious about why you are thinking about doing this. Typically, the only time you'd use `__dict__` is if you were implementing `__getattr__` (not to be confused with `__getattribute__`).

It's also rare that giving objects (esp those of fundamental types) ad-hoc attributes is a good idea. An alternative that's usually viable is to use your own map e.g.

```
>>> def foo(): pass
... 
>>> my_x_values = {foo: 'X'}
>>> my_x_values[foo]
'X'
```

Not everyone agrees about this though. Check out this other SO question: [Python function attributes - uses and abuses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338101/python-function-attributes-uses-and-abuses)