# Static member of a function in Python ?

Tags: python, static-members

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Static class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)
>   [What is the Python equivalent of static variables inside a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279561/what-is-the-python-equivalent-of-static-variables-inside-a-function)

How can I use static fields in Python ?

for example i want to count how many times the function has been called - how can i do this  ?

Comment: @PaulManta: I disagree. Your link is not related to class static fields (as OP says), but to " _the static member at the function level, as opposed to the class level_ ", as stated by OP within the question you gave use link to.

Comment: @Tadeck The word 'class' doesn't even appear in the question... But the phrase 'static member **of a function**' does.

Comment: @PaulManta: Please read the question you linked to again - there are both words: " _class_ " **and** " _function_ ". In the current question (this question) there is a reference to " _static fields_ ". Because of that, and because I have never heard of " _static fields_ " in reference to static variables within function, but I have heard of " _static fields_ " in reference to static member variables of a class, I assumed the current question is about static member variables of a class. Unless you will prove otherwise, I suppose the upvotes of my first comment mean some support in this matter.

Comment: @Tadeck Regarding votes: Good for you, here are two internet credits. Seriously, what's the argument about? The example is clear, he wants to know how to count how many times a function was called. In lack of a better term he used the rather incorrect 'static fields', but his intention is still clear from the example and title. Where's the problem?

Comment: @Tadeck The word 'class' [appears](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279561/what-is-the-python-equivalent-of-static-variables-inside-a-function) in this context, 'how does one implement the static member at the function level, **as opposed to the class level**'. Lol at you making such a big deal out of this.

Comment: @PaulManta: You may be right, but chances are that I am right. I was not making this a "big deal", you did (I just followed). And the upvotes usually mean support. Got it? Now, OP **clearly** refers to static fields and mentions **example use**: " _**for example** i want to count how many (...)_ ". Got it? He tries to clarify what he meant by giving some example usage. My solution also fits for this use case scenario, thus I still think your claim (that my interpretation is incorrect and yours is correct) is baseless. Thanks.

Comment: @Tadeck Now we're getting trolls on SO as well?

Comment: @PaulManta: Please talk about the actual problem OP had, if you are able to help. And use **real** arguments in order to support what you are saying. Otherwise what you are doing is indeed [trolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_(Internet)). Regards.

Comment: @Tadeck I did try to help. What I don't get is why you're so argumentative about this.

Comment: @PaulManta: We have two different opinions and you did not convince me. Do not treat this discussion personally, it is great if many people have different opinions. For me it would be enough to see the list of possible duplicates on the top of the question (as it is now), so anyone can have own judgement. But since you started discussion, I have just replied by mentioning, why I disagree. Is it offending to you? Or is it trolling? I do not think so, unless you stop giving reasonable arguments and start treating this personally. Deal with the fact that other people may have different opinions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you wish to count how many times a method has been called, no matter which instance called it, you could use a class member like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    calls=0            # <--- call is a class member
    def baz(self):
        Foo.calls+=1

foo=Foo()
bar=Foo()
for i in range(100): 
    foo.baz()
    bar.baz()
print('Foo.baz was called {n} times'.format(n=foo.calls))
# Foo.baz was called 200 times
```

---

When you define `calls` this way:

```
class Foo(object):
    calls=0
```

Python places the key-value pair ('calls', 0) in `Foo.__dict__`.

It can be **accessed** with `Foo.calls`. 
Instances of `Foo`, such as `foo=Foo()`, can access it with `foo.calls` as well.

To **assign** new values to `Foo.calls` you must use `Foo.calls = ...`.
Instances can not use `foo.calls = ...` because that causes Python to place a new and different key-value pair in `foo.__dict__`, where instance members are kept.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a decorator adding counting to a function.

```
import functools

def count_calls(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def decor(*args, **kwargs):
        decor.count += 1
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    decor.count = 0
    return decor
```

Usage:

```
>>> @count_calls
... def foo():
...     pass
...
>>> foo.count
0
>>> foo()
>>> foo.count
1
```

Comment: the decorator might be better called `count_calls`

Comment: It's quite the most complicated way of doing it, isn't it ?

Comment: @Patryk: Not at all; defining a decorator means you can count calls on any number of functions by adding a single line prefixing the function definition. Using the class attribute to count calls to a method doesn't generalize like that (it could, but it would end up equivalent to the decorator solution, more verbose, and likely somewhat slower).

Answer (score 4):

Here is some example counting the number of calls of all objects of the same class:

```
class Swallow():
    i = 0 # will be used for counting calls of fly()
    def fly(self):
        Swallow.i += 1
```

And this is the proof:

```
>>> a = Swallow()
>>> b = Swallow()
>>> a.fly()
>>> a.i
1
>>> Swallow.i
1
>>> b.fly()
>>> b.i
2
>>> Swallow.i
2
```

so you can read it by giving the object name or class name.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one simplistic way to do it:

```
def func():
    if not hasattr(func, 'counter'):
        func.counter = 0
    func.counter += 1
    counter = 0 # Not the same as `func.counter`
    print(func.counter)
```

Or if you don't like the if being executed on every call, you can do:

```
def func():
    func.counter += 1
    print(func.counter)
func.counter = 0
```