# Python Class member variables initilialization?

Tags: python, class

Came across one Python Class and I am finding it hard to understand how and why its working . A simplified example of the class is :

```
class Test:
  def __init__(self):
    self.var = 1

  otherVar = 2

  def myPrinter(self):
    print self.__dict__  # Prints {'var': 1}
    print self.var
    print self.otherVar  # Doubt !!
    print self.__dict__  # Prints {'var': 1}

ob = Test()
ob.myPrinter()
```

My doubt is with the `self.otherVar` call not throwing an error while `self.__dict__` does not show reference to `otherVar`

Comment: It looks normal to me. Simply prints `NULL` or similar strategy. If you assign to it, then you will have it in `__dict__` output.

Comment: thanks @Adam , That sort of clears my doubts . But what I dont understand is why is the variable `otherVar` not in the scope of `myPrinter()` i.e. why cant I just do `print otherVar` inside `myPrinter()`

Comment: because it is a part of the class itself and must be referenced via `self.otherVar` similar to how you would call methods inside each other.

Comment: Yeah makes sense . So when will we generally use a class Variable ? I know its shared across class instances , so is that its main purpose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `otherVar` is an attribute of the `class`, while the `var` you setup in the `__init__` is an attribute of the instance.

The `otherVar` is visible to the instance, because python first tries to get the instance attribute values, if the instance doesn't have it, then it checks its class attributes. If you define a `var` in both with different values, things may get confusing at first.

Well, do you know that comparison that a class is like a blueprint and the instance is the object built following it, right? So, `var` is an extra you added while creating the instance.

If you want to see `otherVar`, do `Test.__dict__`. It won't show you `var`, but all the class attributes.
Play a little with it and with time you are going to get used to it. Class attributes may be tricky, but extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

`otherVar` is a class member, not instance member, that's why it doesn't show in `__dict__`.

It appears in `self.__class__.__dict__`. (this way doesn't work in Python 2.x)

By the way, `otherVar` member value is shared across all instances and also accessible from `type` object: `Test.otherVar`

Example here: https://trinket.io/python3/d245351e58

For a more in depth explanation check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12409963/3990806)