# How to access elements from __init__ constructor

Tags: python, class

I have a class like the one given below:

```
class Someclass(object):
    def __init__(self, n1=5, n2=12):
        self.n1 = n1
        self.n2 = n2
```

I will like to use the arguments of `__init__` from the aforementioned class in a function which I am defining in the following manner:

```
def Search(model: Someclass):
    n11 = 10
    n22 = 20
    print( type(model.__init__), type(model) )
    # I want to multiply self.n1 with n11 , and self.n2 with n22 using this function.


Search(Someclass)
>> <class 'function'> <class 'type'>
```

How can I access elements in `__init__` constructor in `Someclass` inside `Search`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are properties on the class-instance. If `isinstance(m, Someclass)` you can simply use `m.n1` and `m.n2`:

```
class Someclass(object):
    def __init__(self, n1=5, n2=12):
        self.n1 = n1
        self.n2 = n2

def Search(model: Someclass):
    n11 = 10
    n22 = 20

    # Like So:
    mul = model.n1 * model.n2

    print( type(model.__init__), type(model) , mul)


Search(Someclass(5,10))
```

Output:

```
<class 'method'> <class '__main__.Someclass'> 50
```

---

This works in *this* case because the parameters are stored as instance variables at/on your instance - it would not work on params that do not get stored:

```
class Forgetful():
    def __init_(self,p1=2,p2=3,p3=4):
        print(p1,p2,p3)   # only consumed, not stored

f = Forgetful()   # prints "2 3 4" but does not store, values no longer retrievable
```

---

Doku:

- official documentation: [class and instance variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)
- read more about class attribute/instance attributes in [Python Class Members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409714/python-class-members)

Comment: The documentation uses _instance variable_ whereasthe linked SO post uses  _instance attribute_ - they are used synonymly for the same thing.