# Why does updating a class attribute not update all instances of the class?

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class A:
    arr = []
```

If I append to `arr` for an instance of `A`, all instances of `A` are updated.

```
>>> a1, a2 = A(), A()
>>> a1.arr.append(0)
>>> a1.arr
[0]
>>> a2.arr
[0]
>>> A.arr
[0]
```

However, if I set `arr` to an array literal for an instance of `A`, other instances are *not* updated:

```
>>> a1.arr = [1,2,3]
>>> a1.arr
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a2.arr
[0]
>>> A.arr
[0]
```

*Why does this occur? When the class attribute is a list, why are there different results between `append` and `=`?*

I also noticed similar behavior when the class attribute is not an array:

```
class B:
    value = ''
```

```
>>> b1, b2 = B(), B()
>>> b1.value = 'hello'
>>> b1.value
'hello'
>>> b2.value
''
>>> B.value
''
```

```
>>> B.value = 'goodbye'
>>> b1.value
'hello'
>>> b2.value
'goodbye'
>>> B.value
'goodbye'
```

*Why does the behavior seem different when the class attribute is a string? When `b1`'s value is already set, why does `B.value = ...` only update `b2`'s value and not `b1`'s?*

Comment: When you reach a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful answers and accept the best (even if you have to write it yourself).  This allows Stack Overflow to archive your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confused over the handling of class attributes and instance attributes.  An instance attribute will *default* to the class attribute.  However, when you specifically change an instance, you create an instance attribute.  Let's walk through your sequence with class B:

```
class B:
    value = ''
# You have a single attribute, `B.value`

b1, b2 = B(), B()
b1.value = 'hello'
# This shadows b1's reference to B.value,
# inserting a local reference to its own attribute of the same name.
# You can check this with the id() function

b2.value   # this still refers to the class attribute.
```

Is it clear from here?

Comment: Using the `id()` function really cleared this one up - exposes that `b2.value` still refers to `B.value`, while `b1.value` (after it is set to `hello`) does not refer to `B.value`

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12409963/4739755) explains what's happening.

In the class `A`, `arr` is a *class attribute*:

> ...all instances of Foo [A] share foovar [arr]

When you `.append()`, you're operating directly on the list object `arr`. When you assign (`a1.arr = [1, 2, 3]`), you're creating a new list object and assigning it as an instance attribute (effectively `self.arr`) on `a1` that takes priority over the class attribute `A.arr`.

> If we don't touch foovar, it's the same for both f and Foo. But if we change f.foovar... << code snippet >> ...we add an instance attribute that effectively masks the value of Foo.foovar. Now if we change Foo.foovar directly, it doesn't affect our foo instance:

Answer (score 1):

When you define a `class variable`, and you assign a list to it, the address of the list would be assigned to the `class variable`:

```
class A:
    arr = []
```

That's why in the first case, when you append `0` to `arr`, it would be added to all object's `arr`.

When you assign `a1.arr = [1,2,3]`, the address of `arr` in object `a1` changes, that's the reason `a2.arr` doesn't change !

And about the second case, you are assigning the value of a string variable to `value`. so if you change `b1.value`, it doesn't change `b2.value`

```
class B:
    value = ''
```

By the way in other languages, this problem is exactly about the difference between `reference` and `value`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class C:
    class_attribute=2

    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_attribute='boo'
```

if you query an attribute of a class instance (`my_instance.foo`), the returned value is instance attribute if it exists, if not class attribute

if you assign to an instance(`my_instance.foo = 42`), an instance attribute is created, it can have the same name,  and it shadows the class attribute

Answer (score 0):

## Name and Bind: What does "=" do

In a short word, Python doesn't have real **variable**. The **variable** you see is actually a **name**(like the **alias** in other languages). And the operator `=`, which is always called **Assignment**, **bind** the name to an **object**. (In Python, everything is an object)

For example:

```
x = 3
```

The `=` doesn't really change the value of `x`, coz actually there is no variable `x` contain a value.
Instead, it creates a **immutable object** `3` and makes `x` a name **bind** to it.(similar to C++'s **reference**)

So, if we do

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = a
>>> print(id(a)) # id(object) will return the address of object in memory
2426261961288
>>> print(id(b))
2426261961288
>>> a is b # operator "is" evaluate whether a and b refer to the same object.  
True
>>> b.append(3)
>>> print(id(b)) # b's address didn't change
2426261961288
>>> print(a)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> print(b)
[1, 2, 3]
```

First, `a = [1,2]` binds the name `a` to an **mutable object**, which is a list `[1, 2]`.(For better understanding, I would annotate this underlying object a nickname *OBJ_288*)
Then, `b = a` binds `b` to the same **object** which `a` reference to, *OBJ_288*.
You can see, `id(a)` is the same as `id(b)`, which means their **addresses** are the same.
`b.append(3)` actually change the object `b` is bound to(as `b.append` refers to a method of *OBJ_288*). Now *OBJ_288* becomes `[1, 2, 3]`, to whom `a` and `b` are bound to.
So when we `print(a)` and `print(b)`, the results are the same.

However, if we do

```
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> a is b
False
>>> id(a)
2426261961288
>>> id(b)
2426262048840
>>> print(a)
[1, 2, 3]
```

When we call operator`=` for `b`, `b` will bind to another **object** (here is the new object we created by [4, 5, 6], let's nickname it *OBJ840*)
While `a` still refers to *OBJ_288*, `print(a)` is still `[1, 2, 3]`

For detail, please see the following references (If you have knowledge of C++, you could understand the first 2 references easier):
https://realpython.com/pointers-in-python/#names-in-python
https://eev.ee/blog/2012/05/23/python-faq-passing/
Also, the detailed rules are stated in Python Official Reference.
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding

## Scope, Class attribute and Instance attribute

In your code:

```
class A:
    arr = []
>>> a1, a2 = A(), A()
>>> a1.arr.append(0)
```

`a1` is an instance of `class A`, and in Python, for attribute name resolution, *every instance creates a namespace, which is the first place in which **attributes** references are searched, if not found, it will continue searching in its class namespace(where the **class attributes** are)*.
So in your case, since `a1` has no instance attr named `arr`, it refers to class A's attribute `A.arr`. and `append` is `A.arr`'s method, which would modify `A.arr`, which results:

```
>>> A.arr
[0]
```

But if you do

```
>>> a1.arr = [1,2,3]
```

Remember I said in **Name and Bind: What does "=" do**, the **=** assignment would binds its left hand side name to its right hand side object.
Also, in Python, *assignments to names always go into the innermost scope(except specified by `global` or `nonlocal`)*. Here it means, it will bind **object** [1,2,3] to `a1.arr`, which is `a1`'s instance attribute, even it doesn't exist before.
Now `a1` has a new **instance attribute** `arr`, so `a1.arr`, as the attribute name resolution rule, it will shadow `A.arr`. That's why:

```
>>> a1.arr
[1, 2, 3]
```

And class A's class attribute `A.arr` is not affected.

```
>>> a2.arr
[0]
>>> A.arr
[0]
```

Reference:
https://docs.pythonorg/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy item **Class instances**
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects

Answer (score -1):

If your asking how to avoid this?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ls = []
a,b = A(), A()
a.ls.append(0)
```

using

> __init__() will make the instances individual

Here's an example of what you're doing..

```
class B:
ls = []
def __init__(self):
    pass


c,d = B(),B()
c.ls == d.ls
Out[21]: True
```

As you can see they still reference the same variable from the B's object.

This is because

> One is a class attribute, while the other is an instance attribute.

So the list ls that is declared outside the instantiation is being `shared by all the instances of B`.

Comment: This is not an answer to the OP ! the question is why this happens? you are answering how to prevent it

Comment: I understand what an instance variable is, don't think this answers the question. I'm wondering about class attributes, explicitly.