# Initializing Functions Like a Class

Tags: python, function, initialization, generator

Many times I have had a need to have a simple function do something different when first called. There are many reasons, but usually I would need a variable initialized differently if the first run through. Sometimes I could handle the problem outside the function or inside, but things could sometimes get messy, and I don't like to use "globals" if I can avoid them.

My solution came from generators. I found that I could "initialize" a function, or "prime" a function as I call it, by using a next() call in the program combined with a reveresed "yield" above a loop in the function. Works like a charm.

Now my question is: Is there a better way that I may be missing?

A WoNUX--working, but non-useful exammple:

```
o_PrintList = g_PrintThis() ## Creates func object
o_PrintList.next() ## 'Primes' the func
o_PrintList.send(9) ## Sends argument to the func
o_PrintList.send(10) ## Another argument to the func

def g_PrintThis():
    v_PrintList = [] ## Inits the variable. If stnd func call this would happen everytime
    print("Initialized")
    v_Num = yield ## Waits for first send argument
    while True: ## Infinite loop. Could be a for loop, etc.
        v_PrintList.append(v_Num) ## Reason v_PrintList needs 'primed'
        if not v_PrintList:
            print("PrintList is empty:")
        else:
            print("Printlist: %s") %(v_PrintList)
        v_Num = yield ## Waits for next send argument, if ever one comes
```

Thanks.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279561/what-is-the-python-equivalent-of-static-variables-inside-a-function

Comment: If you're explicitly calling `next` to prime it, you might as well just have a separate `setup_printing` function and call that for first-time setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to just use an actual class. You can implement `__call__` to define the appropriate behaviour when called:

```
class PrintThis(object):

    def __init__(self, print_list=None):
        if print_list is None:
            print_list = []
        self.print_list = print_list

    def __call__(self):
        if self.print_list:
            print("Print list: {0}".format(self.print_list))
        else:
            print("Print list empty.")

    def send(self, item):
        self.print_list.append(item)
```

In use:

```
>>> p = PrintThis()
>>> p()
Print list empty.
>>> p.send(9)
>>> p.send(10)
>>> p()
Print list: [9, 10]
```

Comment: @jonsharpe Thanks. Certainly a class would work, however for a simple function it becomes a lot of code and more complex. I also tend to classify and use functions as "tasks" and classes as "entities." I send stuff to tasks to be done and returned and I send entities to go and do and hold things. For a simple task, do I really want to create an entity? Food for thought.

Comment: @Raw_Input your task and entity distinction doesn't really apply in Python generally or your example specifically; in this case, you want your task to also hold things!

Answer (score 1):

In Python functions can have attributes, so testing whether a given attribute exists will allow you to determine whether initialization is required:

```
def f(args):
    if not hasattr(f, "guard"):
        print "Initializing"
        f.guard = None
    print "Called with", args

f("one")
f("two")
```

prints

```
Initializing
Called with one
Called with two
```

This avoids the use of global variables, which often represent troublesome potential problems (what if other code uses the same global variable, to ask only one pertinent question).

Comment: Settings attributes on a function from within the function's body is brittle at best. If you need state, use a class (or eventually a closure...).

Comment: @holdenweb Thanks. This is a form of a solution that I often resulted to. However it could get complex at times and/or break on subsequent calls.

Comment: Explain, please? I rather disagree with Bruno about the brittleness of this solution, and particularly find it objectionable to have to declare a class of which I know there'll be only one instance.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are classes too (first class, to be exact). When you call a function, you actually call the function's class' `__call__` method which is also a class.

Like what jonrsharpe said, create a class and implement `__init__`and `__call__` methods.

Comment: Much of what you say is correct, but if functions were classes we would be able to inherit from them. They are instances of the function type.

Comment: And you *can't* inherit `types.FunctionType`.

Comment: Yes, it's remarkably difficult to build a functin on the fly (as it is a module). They may be first-class object, but they aren't really first-class types