# Initialization of variable in python and C

Tags: python, c, initialization

I'm rewriting a C code to python but it seems I've stuck.

I have the function in C:

```
  double GetArrival()
  /* ---------------------------------------------
  * generate the next arrival time, with rate 1/2
  * ---------------------------------------------
  */ 
  {
  static double arrival = START;

  SelectStream(0); 
  arrival += Exponential(2.0);
  return (arrival);
  }
```

This function is called from a `main()` function. As you can see every time it is called,
an exponential random rate of 2.0 is added to arrival. All you have to know is that it's a custom function that returns a random variable.

After consulting ddd on the C file which works as it should, I realized that in the following python "equivalent" the variable `arrival` gets initialized to START = 0 everytime the function GetArrival() is called. This for some reason doesn't happen in the C, except the first time the function is called.

```
def GetArrival():
     arrival = START
     SelectStream(0)
     arrival += Exponential(2.0)
     return arrival
```

So I thought I should omit this evil initialization and that should do it. Did not, because in that case I get the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'arrival' referenced before assignment
```

Which kinda makes sense.

So my question is how can I make the python code work like the one in C, without having the variable `arrival` initialize to zero every time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with how python treats the static variable differently from C I think.  Try referring to making a static variable in python (static var in function, not class).  [This stack overflow reference should be of help to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279561/what-is-the-python-equivalent-of-static-variables-inside-a-function).

Comment: This is caused by the static variable (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable) not differences in "execution stack".

Comment: Thanks @jonls.  Updated accordingly.