# static variable in a function with Python Decorator

Tags: python, static-variables, python-decorators

I was looking for about static value in Python.

And I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279561/what-is-the-python-equivalent-of-static-variables-inside-a-function).

```
def static_var(varname, value):
    def decorate(func):
        setattr(func, varname, value)
        return func
    return decorate

@static_var("counter", 0)
def foo():
    foo.counter += 1
    print "Counter is %d" % foo.counter
```

It is using python decorator for static variable in a function.

The decorator`(static_var)` initialize static value`(foo.counter)` before returning the function`(foo)` decorated.

So I think it should not work as expected, because decorator`(static_var)` initialize `foo.counter` every time when `foo` is called.

As a result, I think if foo() is called two times, it should print `1` two times

```
foo()     
foo()
```

But It prints `1` and `2`, increasing `foo.counter`

Why...?

Why isn't `foo.counter` initialized to `0` every time when foo is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because:

```
def static_var(varname, value):
    def decorate(func):
        setattr(func, varname, value)
        return func
    return decorate


@static_var("counter", 0)
def foo():
    foo.counter += 1
    print "Counter is %d" % foo.counter
```

is equivalent to:

```
foo = static_var("counter", 0)(foo)
```

Notice that `static_var()` actually gets called? Now walk through your decorator; in fact step through it with `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

> Decorators *wrap* other functions potentially either mutating them or
>   returning new functions or both.

See: [Understanding Python Decorators in 12 easy steps](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/)

If we stick a few `print`(s) in your decorator watch what happens:

```
def static_var(varname, value):
    print "1"

    def decorate(func):
        print "2"
        setattr(func, varname, value)
        return func
    print "3"
    return decorate


@static_var("counter", 0)
def foo():
    foo.counter += 1
    print "Counter is %d" % foo.counter


foo()
foo()
```

Output:

```
$ python foo.py
1
3
2
Counter is 1
Counter is 2
```

> So as I said above; firstly `static_var("counter", 0)` is called;
>   then the return of that (*which returns a function*) is called with
>   `foo` as it's first argument which sets up the initial "counter" and
>   returns the same argument (*the function `foo`*).

Answer (score 2):

"foo.counter initialized to 0 every time when foo is called?"

Short answer: No, `foo.counter` is set to 0 only when `static_var` is called.

I think maybe you have little confusion with decorator and the function decorator created.

```
@decorator
def func():
    pass
```

Is just a syntax sugar for

```
func = decorator(func)
```

With this, we will know that your prior code is equal to:

```
def foo():
    foo.counter += 1
    print "Counter is %d" % foo.counter

foo = static_val(foo, "counter", 0)
```

Then, when you are calling `foo()`, you are calling the new `foo` function, not `static_val` in which `counter` attribute will be set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you see is correct. The decorator is executed once only when declared, not on each invocation of the decorated function. Therefore `foo.counter` is initialised to 0 only once.

Think about what a static variable is. Typically (e.g. in C) it is a local variable of a function that persists across calls to the function. The same affect is being achieved here through use of a decorator aptly named `static_var`, so it makes sense that `foo.counter` is incremented each time that `foo()` is called, and not reset.