# Python: remember module function call values

Tags: python, function, module, state

I want to run a third-party python program `thirdparty.py` the way I want. I CANNOT change the code of `thirdparty.py` directly, so I change the external module used by `thirdparty.py`. The code of `thirdparty.py` is like:

```
import module_a

def somefunc():
    ...
    module_a.add(value)
```

So I create my own `module_a.py` and rewrite its `add(value)` function:

```
# module_a.py created by me

def add(value):
    # code written by me
    do_something()
```

Now my problem is, how can I remember the `value` everytime `module_a.add(value)` is invoked by `thirdparty.py`?

My current workaround is to write the `value` back to an external file in `do_something()`. However, I don't want any external file and I/O involved. Also,  I can neither use a class in `module_a.py` to maintain the states, nor change the signature of `add(value)`, otherwise `module_a.add(value)` in `thirdparty.py` won't work.

Ideally I want to write another class to interact with `module_a.py` and remember the value passed to `add(value)` everytime, but how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean remember the value? What do you want to do with the remembered value?

Comment: I think you might have [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem) here. Why can't you wrap thirdparty.py in a module you wrote?  Do you want to track module_a calls?

Comment: When `module_a.add()` gets called it will be called with a new value -- why do you need to remember the old value?  And which old value do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your question as asked is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279561/what-is-the-python-equivalent-of-static-variables-inside-a-function). You can set internal variables for python functions like so:

```
def add(value):
    # code written by me
    add.state = add.state+1 
    do_something()
add.state = 0
```