# Trying to create generator object but getting function object that doesn't respond to generator calls

Tags: python, generator

I'm trying to write an infinite generator that will repeat every positive integer n times. So for example, if I create `f = inf_repeat(3)`, printing the output of `f` 10 times would result in:

```
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4
```

I am close but not quite there. Here's what I've got:

```
    # courtesy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279561/what-is-the-python-equivalent-of-static-variables-inside-a-function
    # a generator that yields items instead of returning a list
    def static_var(varname, value):
        def decorate(func):
            setattr(func, varname, value)
            return func
        return decorate

    def inf_repeat(k):
        count_limit = k
        @static_var("counter", 0)
        @static_var("number", 0)
        def func():
            while True:
                if  func.counter == count_limit:
                    func.counter = 0
                    func.number += 1
                func.counter += 1
                yield func.number
        return func
```

My problem is that this doesn't behave entirely like an iterator. The following commands work:

```
f3 = inf_repeat(3)
print next(f3())
```

But it's irritating to have to call `f3` with parens. I'd like to be able to use the standard iterator syntax I've seen, such as:

```
print(f3.next())
```

and

```
new_list = [iter(f3)]*5
```

What do I need to modify in my function to get to that point? Looking at a variety of generator tutorials, it seemed that `yield` was sufficient to create a generator, but clearly that's not the case.

Also I have no objective to using a module. I checked `itertools` but maybe I missed something that could do what I want without all this code?

Comment: What if you just do `f3 = inf_repeat(3)()`?  Is that good enough for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call the generator object (what you called `f3`) at some point.  You can call it when you create it:

```
f3 = inf_repeat(3)()
```

or even inside `inf_repeat`

```
# change last line to this
return func()
```

Putting `yield` in your function makes it a generator function --- that is, a function that, when called, returns a generator.  If you want to get the generator, you need to call your generator function at some point.

Incidentally, your implementation is needlessly complex.  You can get your desired behavior much more simply without all those decorators and nested functions:

```
def inf_repeat(k):
    number = k
    while True:
        yield number // k
        number += 1
```

Then:

```
>>> list(itertools.islice(inf_repeat(3), 10))
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]
>>> list(itertools.islice(inf_repeat(4), 13))
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Also thanks for your reworked example. For some reason I was worried about different generators sharing properties, but you showed me how a generator is just a function. Each one is its own function call so I don't need to worry about overlap, apparently? Will need to read up on this more.

Comment: @sunny: Right, if you call `inf_repeat` multiple times, the result of each call is a separate generator with its own state (i.e., its own 'static" local variables).  It won't share state with anything else unless it's referencing global variables or external objects you pass in as arguments or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution:

```
def inf_repeat(N):
    i = 1
    while True:
        for n in range(N):
            yield i
        i += 1

# Testing:
f = inf_repeat(3)
for j in range(10):
    print f.next()
```

Here's a solution using itertools:

```
def inf_repeat(N):
    return chain.from_iterable(repeat(i, N) for i in count(1))
```

Comment: Why not use `for f in inf_repeat(3): print f`?

Comment: @Jkdc: Because `inf_repeat` is infinite, so that would be an infinite loop.

Comment: That should work but the program will never end and I'm making it clear that OP can call `.next()` as desired.

Comment: @AlexHall thanks a lot for showing me this. I knew that I must be doing too much, and now it seems so obvious seeing this simple example. I got all into thinking I'd have some sort of shared object problem, but now I see a generator is more like spinning off a function even when you don't do it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using itertools

```
import itertools as it

def inf_repeat(k):
    for i in it.count(1):
        for j in [i]*k:
            yield j

for n in inf_repeat(3): print n
```

produces

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(n):
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i // n
        i += 1
```