# How to avoid global variable in temperature script?

Tags: python

I've written code below to retrieve the current temperature from openweathermap
, when the connection fails it should return the previous temperature.

Everything is working but i would like to avoid using the global variable
**last_temperature** to save the previous retrieved temperature , how can I do this?

```
import time    
from pyowm import OWM

API_key="**********************************"
owm=OWM(API_key)
last_temperature= 15.0

def getcurrentTemperature(city_id): # Gent is 2797656
    global last_temperature 
    try:
        obs = owm.weather_at_id(city_id) #by ID
        w = obs.get_weather()
        temps=w.get_temperature(unit='celsius')
        last_temperature = round(temps['temp'],1)
        return last_temperature
    except:
        return last_temperature

while 1 :
    print getcurrentTemperature(2797656)
    time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: Why did you think you need it?

Comment: You could pass ```last_temperature``` as an argument to ```getcurrentTemperature()```.

Comment: Alternatively, you could make `last_temperature` an attribute of the object `getcurrentTemperature`.

Answer (score 1):

You have several design options:

- You could use a static_var as described here: [What is the Python equivalent of static variables inside a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279561/what-is-the-python-equivalent-of-static-variables-inside-a-function)
- You could implement a class with last_temperature as class member.  The using code would then have the responsibility to create and hold the class instance.
- Or the option described by user2233706 (providing last_temperature as function argument to getcurrentTemperature)

I'd avoid the global variable and also the static_var approach, as they both correspond to static state.  For example, when creating unit-tests you would always have to keep this state set up and cleaned to avoid cross-dependencies between tests.

Answer (score 0):

As user2233706 says, you can simply pass `last_temperature` as an argument to `getcurrentTemperature()`.

You can also skip returning the temperature in `try` and `except` and instead calculate it and then return it in `finally`.

```
import time    
from pyowm import OWM

API_key="**********************************"
owm=OWM(API_key)
last_temperature = 15.0

def getcurrentTemperature(city_id, last_temperature): # Gent is 2797656
    try:
        # If it works it will set the temperature
        obs = owm.weather_at_id(city_id) # by ID
        w = obs.get_weather()
        temps=w.get_temperature(unit='celsius')
        temperature = round(temps['temp'],1)
    except:
        # If it doesn't then simply set the return value to the current temperature
        temperature = last_temperature
    finally:
        # You don't need to include the return in both places - this will be run either way
        return temperature

while 1 :
    current_temperature = getcurrentTemperature(2797656, last_temperature) # Get the current temp
    print current_temperature
    last_temperature = current_temperature # Now set the last temperature to the current one and repeat
    time.sleep(30)
```

Let me know if this is confusing or unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using it in other parts of your code otherwise it wouldn't make a lot of sense.

For me the most logical way would be to create a class like this:

```
class TemperatureData:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.temperature = 15.0

    def update(self, city_id):
        try:
            temperature = own.weather_at_id(city_id).get_weather().get_temperature(unit='celsius')
            self.temperature = round(temperature['temp'], 1)
        except:
            # please catch only the necessary exceptions, not all of them at once, otherwise you might jsut miss important issues on your code 
            pass

def get_temperature(self):
    return self.temperature
```

Then you can create a TemperatureData object (or several, which is nice), and update them. You even have a get_temperature function that you can customize for example to encode the temperature, or put it in Kelvin.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, you could make `last_temperature` an attribute of your function and return that.

```
def getcurrentTemperature(city_id):
    try:
        # try to compute last_temperature
        getcurrentTemperature.last_temperature = last_temperature
    except SomeException: # you should be more specific here!
        pass

    return getcurrentTemperature.last_temperature

getcurrentTemperature.last_temperature = None
```

Demo with a silly function:

```
>>> def foo(number):
...     try:
...         foo.last_result = int(number)
...     except ValueError:
...         pass
...     return foo.last_result
... 
>>> foo.last_result = None
>>> 
>>> foo(10)
10
>>> foo(23.5)
23
>>> foo('hi')
23
>>> foo('test')
23
>>> foo(11.11)
11
```