# Python decorator function execution

Tags: python, decorator

I have below decorator demonstration code. If I execute it without explicitly calling `greet` function, it is executing `print` statement inside decorator function and outputs `Inside decorator`.

I am unable to understand this behavior of decorator. How the `time_decorator` is called even if I didn't call `greet` function?

I am using Python 3.

```
def time_decorator(original_func):
    print('Inside decorator')
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.clock()
        result = original_func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.clock()
        print('{0} is executed in {1}'.format(original_func.__name__, end-start))
        return result
    return wrapper


@time_decorator
def greet(name):
    return 'Hello {0}'.format(name)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Decorators are called at **start** time *(when the python interpreter reads the code as the program starts)*, not at **runtime** *(when the decorated function is actually called)*.

At runtime, it is the wrapped function `wrapper` which is called and which itself calls the decorated function and returns its result.

So this is totally normal that the `print` line gets executed.

If, i.e, you decorate 10 functions, you will see 10 times the print output. No need to even call the decorated functions for this to happen.

Move the `print` inside `wrapper` and this won't happen anymore.

`Decorators` as well as `metaclasses` are part of what is called **meta-programming** *(modify / create code, from existing code)*. This is a really fascinating aspect of programming which takes time to understand but offers amazing possibilities.

Comment: Thank you @Apero! What is motivation behind calling decorator at compile time? Are there any objects that are called during compile time apart from decorators?

Comment: Yes, metaclasses also modify the classes they are "metaclassing" at compile time, not at runtime. Metaclasses and decorators can be seens like code hacks in a way, because they modify the code they respectively metaclass or decorate, without having to modify the initial code itself. Then whenever this "now code" gets called, the new hacked behaviour will happen.

Answer (score 4):

`time_decorator` **is** executed during function decoration. `wrapper` is not (this is function invoked when decorated `greet()` is called).

`@` is just syntactic sugar. Following code snippets are equivalent.

Decorator syntax:

```
@time_decorator
def greet(name):
    return 'Hello {0}'.format(name)
```

Explicit decoration process - decorator is a function that returns new function based on another one.

```
def greet(name):
    return 'Hello {0}'.format(name)

greet = time_decorator(greet)
```