# How to find the number of times function f is executed?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

The function f is defined as such:

```
def f(a, b):
    if a <= 0 or b <= 0:
        return a + b
    else:
        s = 0
        if b * b % (a + b) != 0:
            s += f(a, b - 3)
        if a * a % (a + b) != 0:
            s += f(a - 2, b)
        if a == b - 1:
            s += f(a - 3, b - 2) 
    return s
```

The question is: "How many times will a function "f" be executed, given f(4, 9)?" For example, for f(0, 0) function "f" will be executed once, since the first time is taken into account as well. Can someone explain to me, how I can find the number of executions? (Examples will be ideal.) Than you in advance!

Comment: You can always pass and return a counter variable to the function. Alternatively, have a look at this question about [Python "static" variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279561/what-is-the-python-equivalent-of-static-variables-inside-a-function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increment a global counter, an int wrapped in a list, incrementing it in the function and printing the result after you call it:

```
i = [0]
def f(a, b):
    i[0] += 1
    if a <= 0 or b <= 0:
        return a + b
    else:
        s = 0
        if b * b % (a + b) != 0:
            s += f(a, b - 3)
        if a * a % (a + b) != 0:
            s += f(a - 2, b)
        if a == b - 1:
            s += f(a - 3, b - 2)

    return s

f(2, 34)
print(i[0])
```

Comment: If you will admit that this is the number of executions of f, I will vote you up!

Comment: @L_Pav, this will increment the counter each time f is called.

Comment: He increments `i[0]` every time the function f is called, so it is indeed the number of executions of f.

Comment: Why a list of one int; can't you use a global int variable instead?

Comment: @Evert, yes you can but I don't like using global so I used a list

Comment: Aha; I would think that if you're using a global variable though, it's better to be explicit about it.

Comment: @Evert, yep but I don't want to encourage or introduce  someone to the global keyword, using a list also gives a good lesson in how changes to a mutable structure inside a function are reflected outside which is something one will come across  a lot more often than the global keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach an attribute to the function:

```
def f(a, b):
    f.num += 1
    if a <= 0 or b <= 0:
        ...
```

Result:

```
>>> f.num = 0
>>> f(0, 0)
0
>>> print(f.num)
1
>>> f.num = 0
>>> f(3, 5)
4
>>> print(f.num)
13
```

Comment: This is correct, but is not very efficient, otherwise - not as one block of code.

Answer (score -1):

I don't trust Global variable because of the highly available scope i.e. global variables are accessible to everyone. Instead, you can keep a recursion variable which counts the number of times the function has been called.

```
def f(a, b, count=0):
    count+=1
    if a <= 0 or b <= 0:
        return [a + b, count]
    else:
        s = 0
        if b * b % (a + b) != 0:
            l = f(a, b - 3,count)
            s += l[0]
            count+=l[1]
        if a * a % (a + b) != 0:
            l = f(a - 2, b, count)
            s += l[0]
            count+=l[1]
        if a == b - 1:
            l = f(a - 3, b - 2, count) 
            s += l[0]
            count+=l[1]

    return [s,count]
```

Comment: This keeps returning `0` for the count.

Comment: Yes, count was not updating. Updating the code. However, do note that you have three 'if' statements and not 'if-elif-else'. Hopefully that is intentional.

Comment: It's still returning incorrect values. With `f(0, 0)`, it'll increment `count` to 1, then immediately return the result of `[0, 2]`.

Comment: Fixed. It now returns 1 for f(0,0).