# Expensive operation done once in a function that is called many times, Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I have a long list of groups in json and I want a little utility:

```
def verify_group(group_id):
    group_ids = set()
    for grp in groups:
        group_ids.add(grp.get("pk"))
    return group_id in group_ids
```

The *obvious* approach is to load the set outside the function, or otherwise declare a global -- but let's assume I don't want a global variable.

In statically typed languages I can say that the set is static and, I believe that will accomplish my aim.  How would one do something similar in python?  That is : the first call initializes the set, **group_ids**, subsequent calls use the set initialized in the first call.

BTW, when I use the [profilestats](https://pypi.org/project/profilestats/) package to profile this little code snippet, I see these frightening results:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      833    0.613    0.001    1.059    0.001 verify_users_groups.py:25(verify_group)
  2558976    0.253    0.000    0.253    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
  2558976    0.193    0.000    0.193    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
```

I tried adding functools.lru_cache -- but that type of optimization doesn't address my present question -- how can I load the set **group_ids** once *inside* a def block?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Haven't tested, but apparently you can store it [as a function attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279561/what-is-the-python-equivalent-of-static-variables-inside-a-function)

Comment: Is this question solved?

Comment: I would say "yes"

Comment: Well, the obvious way to use `lru_cache` here is to refactor your code to have a `def load_group_ids` that *is* cached, and call that from `verify_group`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga IMHO using `lru_cache` to cache a function with no parameters is shooting a fly with a cannon.

Comment: @Bakuriu sure, I agree. Whatever simple caching strategy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an equivalent of `static`, however you can achieve the same effect in different ways:

One way is to abuse the infamous mutable default argument:

```
def verify_group(group_id, group_ids=set()):
    if not group_ids:
        group_ids.update(grp.get("pk") for grp in groups)
    return group_id in group_ids
```

This however allows the caller to change that value (which may  be a feature or a bug for you).

I usually prefer using a closure:

```
def make_group_verifier():
    group_ids = {grp.get("pk") for grp in groups}
    def verify_group(group_id):
        # nonlocal group_ids # if you need to change its value
        return group_id in group_ids
    return verify_group

verify_group = make_group_verifier()
```

Python is an OOP language. What you describe is an instance method. Initialize the class with the set and call the method on the instance.

```
class GroupVerifier:
    def __init__(self):
        self.group_ids = {grp.get("pk") for grp in groups}
    def verify(self, group_id):
        # could be __call__
        return group_id in self.group_ids
```

---

I'd also like to add that it depends by the API design. You could let the take the responsibility of pre-computing and providing the value if they want performance. This is the choice taken by, for example, [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices). The `cum_weights` parameter isn't necessary but it allows the user to remove the cost of computing that array for every call in performance critical code. So instead of having a mutable argument you use `None` as default and compute that set only if the value passed is `None` otherwise you assume the caller did the work for you.

Comment: The closure seems the most elegant for my taste.  I did not think of that!  Thank you,

Comment: @fiacre I'm a fan of that construct. You can often use it to build functions for the `key=` parameters of `sorted` or `groupby` often.