# How do I find where the first call of the function was and return None accordingly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, closures

I was given the following question:

Write a function last_in(x) that returns the value of x used in the previous call. The first time that the function is called, it will return None.

I did something that somewhat works, but something is missing. Here's my attempt:

```
def last_in(x):
    def inner():
        return x

    return inner()
```

And the output of

```
print(last_in(3),last_in(4),last_in(5), last_in("a"),last_in("12"))
```

is

```
3 4 5 a 12
```

But the expected needs to be

```
None 3 4 5 a
```

What do I miss?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an attribute for your function to store previous values, e.g. `last_in.prev_val`. This is somewhat similar to [static variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279561/what-is-the-python-equivalent-of-static-variables-inside-a-function) in other languages. You just need to make sure you handle initializing the attribute appropriately. `getattr` is useful as @Feodoran mentions.

```
def last_in(x):
    return_val = getattr(last_in, 'prev_val', None)
    last_in.prev_val = x
    return return_val

print(last_in(3), last_in(4), last_in(5), last_in("a"), last_in("12"))
```

Ouptput:

```
None 3 4 5 a
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a function `inner` and immediately calling it. So this:

```
def last_in(x):
    def inner():
        return x

    return inner()
```

is roughly equivalent to this:

```
def last_in(x):
    return x
```

What you can do is, define a variable and access it using `global` keyword:

```
last_x = None

def last_in(x):
    global last_x
    return_value, last_x = last_x, x
    return return_value


print(last_in(3), last_in(4), last_in(5), last_in("a"), last_in("12"))
```

```
None 3 4 5 a
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to use a [Mutable Default Argument](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments):

```
def last_in(x, prev=[None]):
    prev.append(x)
    return prev[-2]

print(last_in(3),last_in(4),last_in(5), last_in("a"),last_in("12"))
```

This will produce:

```
None 3 4 5 a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a global list of inputs passed to the function.

```
valueList=[]
def last_in(x):
    def inner():
        valueList.append(x)
        if(len(valueList)!=1):
            return valueList[len(valueList)-2]
        else:
            return None

    return inner()

print(last_in(3),last_in(4),last_in(5), last_in("a"),last_in("12"))
```

**OUTPUT:**
None 3 4 5 a

Answer (score 1):

Functions are objects and can have attributes. You can, therefore, store the previous number as an attribute.

```
def last_in(x):
    if hasattr(last_in, 'last_num'): curr_num = last_in.last_num   
    else: curr_num = None        
    last_in.last_num = x
    return curr_num


print(last_in(2))
print(last_in(3))
print(last_in(4))
```

Output:

```
None
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without global variable:

```
def last_in(x, last = [None]):
    v, last[0] = last[0], x
    return v

print(last_in(3),last_in(4),last_in(5), last_in("a"),last_in("12"))
```

Prints:

```
None 3 4 5 a
```