# how can I change the global variable in each function without the functions affecting each other in Python?

Tags: python, global-variables

My global variable `count=0` is being changed in the function (method) below:

```py
def Counter(counter,boolean=False)->int:
    if boolean:
        counter+=1
    else:
        counter=0

    return counter
```

and other functions uses `Counter` function:

```py
def func1():
    global count
    count=Counter(count,True)
    print("func1:",count)

def func2():
    global count
    count=Counter(count,True)
    print("func2:",count)
```

When run these functions one more time like `for` loop

```py
for _ in range(3):
    func1()
    func2()
```

the output is:

```
func1:1
func2:2
func1:3
func2:4
func1:5
func2:6
```

But output must be like this:

```
func1:1
func2:1
func1:2
func2:2
func1:3
func2:3
```

I researched different ways but could not find an answer. How can I do that?

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: That's pretty much the point of using a global variable. The solution (and better practice, anyway) is to not use a global variable.

Comment: Also, I cannot understand why you think that the code you show *should* produce your desired output when `func1()` and `func2()` are essentially the same function.

Comment: I don't want to use global variables, but I must to use only one variable for counter. I want a different counter to work in both functions. my func1 and func2 is already wrong, i don't know how can i fix.

Comment: the contents of the functions will change, I just wanted to ask in simple form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Why previous code didn't work?***

The `global` keyword makes the counter variable accessible from both functions. 
Using `global` variable is a bad-practice, don't do that.

***How to achieve what you asked?***

The following word assigns a counter for each of the functions, which modify it on each call.

```
def func1():
    func1.count+=1
    print("func1:", func1.count)

def func2():
    func2.count += 1
    print("func1:", func2.count)

func1.count=0
func2.count=0

for _ in range(3):
    func1()
    func2()
```

***More about***

What you ask, is how to use static-variable in a python function. 
The term 'function static variable' refers to a variable that is accessible and owned by a function. 
Python doesn't support static variables in a straight-forward manner such as in languages such as C# or Java, but there are other beautiful solutions in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279561/what-is-the-python-equivalent-of-static-variables-inside-a-function), those are more complex and require the usage of [decorators](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/decorators.html) - so I didn't mention them.

Comment: Your code is useful for me, even if it doesn't give exactly what I want. I'll review these links. I think I'll use something similar to your answer.
thanks for the solution.