# How to pass 1 argument each from 2 functions into 1 function?

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

**I've tried to understand how and why I haven't seen any answers to this specific question.**

I have two `functions` each has an argument `path`

```py
def check_sbb_name(path):
    if path is None:
        DeltaZero_Selenium_Manager.test_sbb_name_textfield(path)
        return path
    else:
        call = sbb_manager_sql()
        name = call.get_new_sbb_name()
        DeltaZero_Selenium_Manager.test_sbb_name_textfield(name)
        
        create_new_sbb("", name)
```

```
def check_sites_for_sbb(path):
    if path is None:
        DeltaZero_Selenium_Manager.test_site_combo_options_alternative_overview(path)
    else:
        call = sbb_manager_sql()
        site = call.connect_site()
        DeltaZero_Selenium_Manager.test_site_combo_options_alternative_overview(site)
        
        create_new_sbb(site, "")
```

Just ignore everything these `functions` actually do, cause everything works just perfectly until
I want to pass on `name` & `site` to the following `create_new_sbb` function

```
def create_new_sbb(site_name, sbb_name):
    mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO sbb_data (site, name, is_deleted) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                         (site_name, sbb_name, 0))
    db.commit()
```

So I want to pass on these arguments to `create_new_sbb` at the same time, instead of calling `create_new_sbb` on each function

> *Note that `create_new_sbb` is located in another file*

**The results in MySql DB:**

[image]

I want `site` and `name` on the same row obviously
So only execute `create_new_sbb` when both arguments have been passed somehow.

Any help is very appreciated!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "calling `create_new_sbb` on each function"? Also, you need a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What do you mean "only execute `create_new_sbb` if both arguments are passed"? If you try to call the function without its required inputs, you'll get a TypeError. If you pass them as None when they aren't defined, well then, check for None before calling the function.

Comment: I need to pass my arguments to 'create_new_sbb' and for that, you have to call it right?

Comment: @Reti43 - Yes I know, But I wonder if there is a workaround, if not. How can I change to make it work?

Comment: You literally do `create_new_sbb("", name)` in your code. Apparently that results in undesired results, so don't do that. Only call your function when both arguments are not empty strings. It's a simple condition check.

Comment: @Reti43 - Can you provide an example?

Comment: `if site != '' and name != '': create_new_sbb(site, name)`

Comment: Apparently, you call alternatively `check_sbb_name` and `check_sites_for_sbb`. You should have one to store its argument *somewhere* and the other to use that stored argument to feed the database.

Comment: @Reti43 - Did not make any difference :(

Comment: Can you prove an answer for how to do it? -  @SergeBallesta

Comment: For that you should explain what `check_ssb_name` and `check_sites_for_ssb` do, how  they are used and whether you call them sequentially. Because as is I see no reason you can't fuse both of them together and get both `site` and `name` from `call` at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume here that you **always** call `check_sbb_name` and `check_sites_for_sbb` in pairs with the same path. I would use:

```
cur_path = None
cur_name = None
cur_site = None

def check_sbb_name(path):
    ...    
    register_name(path, name)      # only register

def check_sites_for_sbb(path):
    ...
    register_site(path, site)      # only register

def register_name(path, name):
    if (path == cur_path) and (cur_site is not None): # other element already registered
        create_new_sbb(cur_site, name)                # ok, we can insert
    else:
        cur_path = path                               # register for this path
        cur_site = None
    cur_name = name

def register_site(path, site):
    if (path == cur_path) and (cur_name is not None):
        create_new_sbb(site, cur_name)
    else:
        cur_path = path
        cur_name = None
    cur_site = site
```

The important part is to register elements and only write to the database when you have a pair. Alternative methods (using same principle) could be used if for example you always call `check_sbb_name` first, then `register_name` would always register `cur_name` (no need for path) and `register_site` would always call `create_new_bb`. Or...

Comment: This almost works, but I managed to solve the rest! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, please consider giving example code of the usage you would make of these functions to make more clear their usage.

To the solution itself, I will propose my solution that uses [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279561/what-is-the-python-equivalent-of-static-variables-inside-a-function):

```py
def func1(value):
    print_two_values(value1 = value)

def func2(value):
    print_two_values(value2 = value)


def static_vars(**kwargs):
    def decorate(func):
        for k in kwargs:
            setattr(func, k, kwargs[k])
        return func
    return decorate

@static_vars(value1="",value2="")
def print_two_values(value1="", value2=""):
    if value1:
        print_two_values.value1 = value1
    
    if value2:
        print_two_values.value2 = value2

    if print_two_values.value1 and print_two_values.value2:
        print(print_two_values.value1, print_two_values.value2)
        print_two_values.value1 = ""
        print_two_values.value2 = ""

func1("Hello")
func2("World")

func2("1")
func1("Test")

func1("This will not")
func1("This will")
func2("be shown")
```

Which will then result in this output

```
Hello World
Test 1
This will be shown
```

Finally, applying this to your code, your `create_new_sbb` would look like

```py
@static_vars(site_name="",sbb_name="")
def create_new_sbb(site_name="", sbb_name=""):
    if site_name:
        create_new_sbb.site_name = site_name

    if sbb_name:
        create_new_sbb.sbb_name = sbb_name

    if create_new_sbb.site_name and create_new_sbb.sbb_name:
        mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO sbb_data (site, name, is_deleted) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                            (create_new_sbb.site_name, create_new_sbb.sbb_name, 0))
        db.commit()
        create_new_sbb.site_name = ""
        create_new_sbb.sbb_name = ""
```

and then to set `site_name` you just call `create_new_sbb(site_name="site name")` and for `sbb_name` you just call `create_new_sbb(sbb_name="sbb name")`.

This solution has some limitations, like shown in the previous output if you are not careful with the order you can have data loss, which can easily happen in multi-thread scenarios, in which case you have a number of potential solutions to avoid creating a bottleneck in this function (instead of N variables, create a buffer array where you have `N_thread * N_variable` as index for each variable) but this is out of the scope of this answer.