# Beginner python question (How to stop variable from being reinitialise in a function)

Tags: python

```
def addList(index):
    listA = [] #WHERE SHOULD I PUT THIS, TO STOP IT FROM BEING REINITIALIZED?
    listA.append(index)
    return listA

def main():
    for i in range(3):
        x = addList(1)
        print(x)
main()
```

I have something like this. I understanding that variables belonging to the function is only accessible within the 'scope'.
But then WHERE will I place my LIST variable to keep it from being altered?

Sorry I am just a beginner and I am trying to figure out a lot of things and best practices.
Thank you.

> The output :
> [1]
> [1]
> [1]
>
> I want:
> [1,1,1]

Comment: You mean you want a [static variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279561/12671057)?

Comment: think about creating a class that holds the list as an instance variable, just pass the class instance as argument, you probably want to do more then just append to a list

Answer (score 0):

You could simply define it outside the function, then pass it in as an argument?

```
def addList(index, myList):
    myList.append(index)
    return myList

def main():
    listA = [] # Here!
    for i in range(3):
        x = addList(1,listA)
        print(x)
main()
```

Alternatively, you could pass in a new Array directly as an argument.
Finally, you could also declare it outside the function scope and make it global, although this is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare your list in in the main() function then pass reference to it to your addList() function like this:

```
def addList(lst, index):
    lst.append(index)
    return lst

def main():
    listA = []
    for _ in range(3):
        x = addList(listA, 1)
        print(x)
main()
```

**Note:**

There are better ways to achieve this

Answer (score -1):

put `listA = []` outside your `addlist()` function. That's why it keeps initialising because it'll reset every time you run it.